# Changing the color of a menu item on hover of a submenu in a sidebar (jsFiddle)

Tags: jquery, css

I am having trouble changing the color of a menu item (.category) on hover of a submenu in a sidebar that I am working on for my website. As you can see in the jsFiddle exmaple below, when a user hovers over a category, a submenu opens up, and when a user hovers a submenu item the hover color is orange. I would like to keep that orange on hover for the submenu items. At the same time, I would like the menu item (category) color to change while the submenu is open, to a light blue.

I tried using css alone to accomplish this but the hover colors change for all children, which is not what I want. I'd appreciate any help in resolving this, as this is an ongoing issue that I have been trying to figure out.

What I tried so far:

```
 $(this).find(".submenu").show().parent().css('color', 'lightblue');
```

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/BGcDc/38/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that links have a high-priority default blue color applied. To change the color, you need to actually change it on the link. I put this in the `hover()` code, and it worked:

```
$(this).find("a").eq(0).css("color", "#2B60DE");
```

This finds the first child link of the `li.category` tag (further child links are the actual menu items) and changes the color to light blue (#2B60DE). In the `mouseleave()` code, put that same code, but leave the actual value blank, like so:

```
$(this).find("a").eq(0).css("color", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to change color on first element and it is working you can check in jsfiddle.

Further you should apply style to class and add/remove class via javascript.

http://jsfiddle.net/BGcDc/41/

Comment: check the first element i add the class on first element only and first answer is great same technique

Answer (score 0):

Not a JQuery solution, but look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8114664/757830) on how to style a parent element.

Especially its second [jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/AGgpN/3/) (pure css2) which does what you are looking for, I think.