# How can I change a div's background, by hovering over another div?

Tags: css, background, background-image, background-color

I'm trying to change an entire page's `body`'s background color, when a user hovers over a thumbnail on that page (the thumbnail being in a `div` within `body`). Is there any way to do so using only CSS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114657/how-to-style-the-parent-element-when-hovering-a-child-element

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer: NO.

You would have to go up, select the `div`'s parent and then the `div`'s parent parent... until you get to the `body`. There is no way to select an element's parent using only CSS (if you'd like to know why, [this article](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors) may prove useful)... yet (there will be a parent selector in [CSS4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/), however).

JavaScript is the way to go if you want to do this and it's quite easy.

If you have something like this:

```
<div class='change-bg'></div>​
```

in your HTML, then the JavaScript is simply:

```
var el = document.querySelector('.change-bg');
el.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}, true);
el.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
}, true);
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/TDSUL/

If you're using jQuery, it gets even easier:

```
$('.change-bg').hover(function(){
    $('body').css({'background': 'red'})},
function(){
    $('body').css({'background': 'black'})
});​​
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/YWDeA/

Comment: I find it best to add it to the bottom of the page and inside of a $(document).ready(function(){...});

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible. Just go with JS, like example:

```
<div data-bgcolor="red"><div>    

$("div").mouseover(function(){
  $("body").css("background-color", $(this).attr("data-bgcolor"));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as such, no. You can change descendants' attributes but not ancestors' via CSS selectors. XPath would allow such things but that's not possible in CSS. So I guess you need to resort to JavaScript in this case.