# Hover on child should turn off hover effect on parent

Tags: css, hover

I have two nested `<div>`'s

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

I want to change the `background` from `.parent` when I hover over `.parent`.

I want the `background` to turn normal again when I hover over `.child`.

For example, when I hover over the inner area I want the outer area to return to its original (gray) state:

```css
.parent {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 50px;
    background: lightgray;
}

.parent:hover {
    background: lightblue;
}

.child {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: darkgray;
}

.child:hover {
    background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to keep this `<div>` structure and I do not want a JavaScript solution (I know the JavaScript solution but I want to keep it pure CSS).

This is not a duplicate of "how to style the parent when hovering over a child". I want to NOT style the parent when hovering over a child.

Comment: keep the divs side by side and use positioning to look them as parent-child elements.

Comment: Don't believe you can with CSS and keep the same HTML structure... hovering on a child will always trigger the hover of the parent. You would have to use a different structure or fake it in another way. With the example it isn't a problem, but I assume it is a problem for a more complex setup.

Comment: "I would like to keep this `<div>` structure"  I don't want to do weird positioning with CSS. tbh.

Comment: @robooneus I thought it also wouldn't but maybe there is something I don't know of, yet.

Comment: Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/k3Zdt/7/).

Comment: @Mr_Green I can't put them next to each other. that's the whole problem

Comment: Then you must go with javascript or jquery.

Comment: I believe there is no appropriate pseudo selector in pure CSS, not even CSS3. What you'd need is something like `:directhover`...

Comment: That is a beautiful example. Such style!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**EDIT 2024**: It's now possible with the newly added `has` selector https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78110861/270209

---

**Old Answer**:

Basically you can't : [How to style the parent element when hovering a child element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114657/how-to-style-the-parent-element-when-hovering-a-child-element)

But a trick is to use a sibling element :
http://jsfiddle.net/k3Zdt/8/

```css
.parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 50px;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #355E95;
  transition: background-color 1s;
  position: relative;
  top: -200px;
}

.child:hover {
  background: #000;
}

.sibling {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 50px;
  top: -50px;
  left: -50px;
  background: #3D6AA2;
  transition: background-color 1s;    
}

.sibling:hover {
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="sibling"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you :) this is exactly it. this is my final sort of result :)  http://jsfiddle.net/k3Zdt/11/

Comment: That's a simple example. but do you have any solution for randomly sized content on child div?

Comment: In 2024, this is now possible with native, cross-browser CSS. See: [the modern CSS solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923922/#answer-78110861).

Comment: @Rounin I've edited the answer to link yours.

Answer (score 14):

You can trick something ;)

Basically, use a `:before` pseudo-element for the child div, with its same size;

when you hover on the child div, enlarge the `:before` pseudo-element to cover the father div area; this will cause the father div `hover` effect to fall down, and then to come back to the original state. A precise combination of z-index is involved too.

> Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gFu8h/ <sup>Dark Magic(tm)</sup>

```css
.parent {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 50px;
    transition: background-color 1s;
    background: #3D6AA2;    
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.parent:hover{
    background: #FFF;    
}

.child {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #355E95;
    transition: background-color 1s;
    position: relative;
}

.child:hover {    
    background: #000;
}

.child:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;        
    z-index: -1;
    transition: background-color 1s;
}

.child:hover:before{
    top: -50px;
    bottom: -50px;
    left: -50px;
    right: -50px;     
    background: #3D6AA2;    
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 cool.. didn't thought about it. :)

Comment: Thanks; this is only a proof-of-concept, it should be adjusted to be more dynamic and to handle the hover-out more properly, if needed (it restores the state only when going out of the father too (that is not the father anymore, because it is the transparent `:before` enlarged)), but at least... it is possible with pure CSS :)

Answer (score 2):

> I want to change the background from .parent when I hover over .parent.
>
> I want the background to turn normal again when I hover over .child.

In 2024, this is now possible with native, cross-browser CSS.

The complex pseudo-selector `:not(:has(div:hover))` will disable a selector from applying to any element where that element contains a descendant `<div>` element which is being `:hover`-ed over.

If you apply `:not(:has(div:hover))` to `div:hover` like this:

```
div:hover:not(:has(div:hover)) {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

you will declare, explicitly, that a `:hover` effect should apply only to the element being `:hover`-ed and *not* to any of its ancestors.

---

**Working Example**

```css
.parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 50px;
  background: lightgray;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: darkgray;
}

div:hover:not(:has(div:hover)) {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```