# CSS: Hovering over a divs with a different z-indexes

Tags: css, hover

Let's say I have to divs named "A" and "B", respectively.

```
<div id="A">
    <div id="B">
    </div>
</div>
```

div A has a z-index of 1 and has a width and height of 100%.
div B has a z-index of 2 and has a width and height of 50% and a top and left of 25%;

```
#A{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%
    height:100%;
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    z-index:1;

    background-color:black;
}

#B{
    position:absolute;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    left:25%;
    top:25%;
    z-index:2;

    background-color:gray
}
```

If you were to hover over Div A and Div B at the same time, Div A will still register as being hovered over. In this hypothetical scenario, whenever I hover over Div A, I want Div A to turn Red and Div B to turn Gray, and whenever I hover over Div B, I want Div B to be Blue and Div A to be Black. How can I do this? **I would prefer a CSS answer if there is one available.**

I would think using `#A:not(hover){}` would work, but when I tried it, it failed.

Answer (score 0):

Your hypothetical situation already exists in the way that you you want:

- Hovering over `A` turns `A` red and `B` gray
- Hovering over `B` turns `B` blue and `A` red

```css
#A {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: black;
}

#A:hover {
  background: red;
}

#B {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  top: 25%;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: grey;
}

#B:hover {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="A">
  <div id="B"></div>
</div>
```

However, if you really **do** want to stop `<div>` `#A` from being hovered over when `<div>` `#B` is hovered over, you can make use of a **sibling** element, as is described in **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17924223/2341603)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: How could I use the answer you linked me in this example? Could you use a Div C to show me?

Comment: Also I made a typo. Div A was suppose to turn black when you hovered over Div B.

Comment: Thanks for the link you sent me. You helped me solve the problem!

Comment: No problem; I knew it involved a sibling element, but couldn't quite get it to work for your specific situation. I'd assume the `z-indexes` were conflicting in some way. Glad to hear you got it sorted though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't with pure css, you must help of jquery :

*Part of Css:*

```
#A:hover  {
    background-color: red;
}

#B:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

*Part of jQuery:*

```
$('#B').hover(function(){
     $('#A').css('background-color','black');
},function(){
     $('#A').css('background-color','red');
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#B').hover(function(){
         $('#A').css('background-color','black');
    },function(){
        $('#A').css('background-color','red');
    })
})
```

```css
#A {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    z-index:1;
    background-color:black;
    border: 1px solid;
}

#B {
    position:absolute;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    left:25%;
    top:25%;
    z-index:2;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-color: gray;
} 

#A:hover  {
    background-color: red;
}

#B:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="A">
    <div id="B">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Div A isn't changing back to black when you hover over Div B. :/

Comment: you said:` I hover over Div B, I want Div B to be Blue and Div A to be Red.`

Comment: Typo. I fixed that.

Comment: It turned black, but it wont turn red again. I want it to be a permanent event.

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko , try again!

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko,how is it?

Comment: It works fine, but I found a css answer. Check mine out.

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko , you change html code.you waste my time only.

Comment: But I didn't use JQuery, which was the whole point of asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve what you're trying to do with CSS. The hover feature only allows you to change the attributes of that one element. I would recommend using JQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#A").hover(function(){

        $("#A").css("background-color", "red");
        $("#B").css("background-color", "gray");

    });
    /* Continue writing other hover functions */

});
```

JQuery allows you to style multiple elements given an action

Comment: you're saying when "A" is not hovered do this. That doesn't have anything to do with what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Have you ever used JQuery?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to use anymore external scripts in my project.

Comment: Why not? Use a JQuery CDN, therefore, it doesn't take up space. Listen, your problem can only be fixed with JQuery, CSS just doesn't have the capabilities

Comment: I found a css answer!! Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I found a pure css way using the link from Obsidian Age's answer:

```
<div id="ContainerDiv">
    <div id="A"></div>
    <div id="B"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k3Zdt/248/

All I had to do was take Div B out of Div A and remove the z-indexes.