# Hover on parent but not on child element

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink, hover

I have an issue where I want to activate hover state on a link when hovering on the container anywhere but except on two buttons `save` and `close`. CSS approach is preferred but if not vanilla JavaScript would be fine. Please have have look I have created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/rajkeshwar-the-bold/pen/aboNrVX)

Comment: You can find this solution/approach in the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923922/hover-on-child-without-hover-effect-on-parent)

Comment: That doesn't fit my requirement too. Since I want to activate hover effect on a link. Hovering a div element is easy but a link within it. Since the link get different background and color if it is a visited link.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1):

You can not trigger pseudo events. you can give it same styling when the box is hovered:

```
.box {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  transition: background .3s ease-in-out;

  &:hover {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    a {
      color: #525199;
      background-color: #e6e6f0;
      border-color: #525199;
    }
  }
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is I don't want hover state on the `link` while hovering on the `Save` or `Cancel` button and that is the challenge.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with pure CSS, as explained on the question [How to style the parent element when hovering a child element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114657/how-to-style-the-parent-element-when-hovering-a-child-element)

The solution, then, is to add some Javascript to style the parent element, for example by adding a class to the parent element. A simple code snippet to achieve this with your solution, would be the following:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.save, .cancel').forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    button.parentNode.parentNode.className = 'box nohover';
  });
  button.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    button.parentNode.parentNode.className = 'box';
  });
});
```

And you'd then need to style the {{nohover}} class by not changing the background:

```
.nohover:hover {
  background: none;
}
```

[See this codepen for a working demo](https://codepen.io/mathias-s/pen/pozyXVm).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.box:hover :not(.box--right):hover a {
    color: #525199;
    background-color: #e6e6f0;
    border-color: #525199;
}
```