# Hover on child without changing parent

Tags: html, css, hover, parent-child

Hover on child element `<button>` without hover effect on parent `<h2>`

```css
.parent {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 31px;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  position: relative;
}

.parent:hover {
  color: orange;
}

span {
  line-height: unset;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  z-index: 5;
}

span button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -20px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  min-width: 30px;
  min-height: 30px;
  z-index: 5;
  background: #0085ba !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="parent">
  Title
  <span class="child">
    <button>+</button>
  </span>
</h2>
```

Comment: You may have to introduce some Javascript to prevent the bubbling. Is that acceptable?

Comment: @AHaworth i guess yes. i already thought about this. cause didn't find any solution with css

Answer (score 3):

This has been asked before, and answers seem to come within the span of: "css can't do that", "you should probably restructure your divs" and "here's a trick".
[hover on child without hover effect on parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923922/hover-on-child-without-hover-effect-on-parent)

Now I don't have the experience to say if a structure that neccesitates this is actually bad, but in either case, there is now a straight-forward solution with :has()

```css
.parent {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 31px;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  position: relative;
}

.parent:not(:has(.child:hover)):hover {
  color: orange;
}

span {
  line-height: unset;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  z-index: 5;
}

span button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -20px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  min-width: 30px;
  min-height: 30px;
  z-index: 5;
  background: #0085ba !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="parent">
  Title
  <span class="child">
    <button>+</button>
  </span>
</h2>
```

This is what that selector is saying in English:
Select all elements ".parent" - except the ones who have any child elements ".child" being hovered on - when they are hovered on.

Answer (score 0):

This can be helpful

example

.html

```
<div class="parent1">
     <div class="child1">
          /*.....*/
```

.css

```
.parent1:hover{
 cursor: pointer;
 }

.parent1:hover .child1{
/*......*/
}
```

snippet

```
.parent:hover .child {
/* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tricky.

First you need to get the parent from the child :

```
const _parent = document.querySelector('selectorOfParentFromChild')
```

After you have to add the class on child and remove on parent. You need to do it one child event : 'onMouseOver'.

SO:

```
[child, parent].forEach(node=>node.addEvenListener('onmouseover', (event)=>{
event.stopPropagation();
const _parent = document.querySelector('selectorOfParentFromChild')

node.classlist.add(wanted)

_parent.classlist.remove(wanted)

})
```

Answer (score -1):

You will have to delete the CSS for `parent:hover` and if you only want the hover effect on the button then the parent shouldn't have a hover effect in your CSS.

```css
.parent {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 31px;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  line-height: unset;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  z-index: 5;
}

span button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -20px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  min-width: 30px;
  min-height: 30px;
  z-index: 5;
  background: #0085ba !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

button:hover {
  color: orange;
}
```

Comment: Why would this make any difference to what happens on hover (other than a color change). The parent still turns orange.

Answer (score -1):

Add the below:

```
parent:hover {
  cursor:pointer
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.