# Apply hover styling only on the element that I am direclty hovering

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I have multiple elements with a class called `h-me`. The markup looks somewhat like this:

```
<span class="h-me">
  <span class="h-me">
    <span class="h-me">
    x
    </span>
    <span class="h-me">
    y
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
.h-me:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);  
}
```

When I am hovering over the `span` tag with content "x", it changes the background of all the `span` elements because I am technically hovering over all of them.

Is there any way to only change the background of the element that I am strictly hovering over?

There are two restriction here.

1. I cannot change the markup in any way. I will have to rely on some CSS or JavaScript trickery to get it done.
2. The markup doesn't stay fixed. It will change very frequently.

The markup will typically be like this:

```
<span class="katex-html" aria-hidden="true"><span class="base"><span class="strut" style="height: 1em; vertical-align: -0.25em;"></span><span style="margin-right: 0.1076em;" class="h-me mathnormal">f</span><span class="mopen">(</span><span class="h-me mathnormal">x</span><span class="mclose">)</span><span class="mspace" style="margin-right: 0.2778em;"></span><span class="mrel">=</span><span class="mspace" style="margin-right: 0.2778em;"></span></span><span class="base"><span class="strut" style="height: 2.3846em; vertical-align: -0.9703em;"></span><span class="mop"><span style="margin-right: 0.4445em; position: relative; top: -0.0011em;" class="mop op-symbol large-op">∫</span><span class="msupsub"><span class="vlist-t vlist-t2"><span class="vlist-r"><span class="vlist" style="height: 1.4143em;"><span class="" style="top: -1.7881em; margin-left: -0.4445em; margin-right: 0.05em;"><span class="pstrut" style="height: 2.7em;"></span><span class="sizing reset-size6 size3 mtight"><span class="h-me mtight"><span class="h-me mtight">−</span><span class="h-me mtight">∞</span></span></span></span><span class="" style="top: -3.8129em; margin-right: 0.05em;"><span class="pstrut" style="height: 2.7em;"></span><span class="sizing reset-size6 size3 mtight"><span class="h-me mtight">∞</span></span></span></span><span class="vlist-s">​</span></span><span class="vlist-r"><span class="vlist" style="height: 0.9703em;"><span class=""></span></span></span></span></span></span><span class="mspace" style="margin-right: 0.1667em;"></span><span class="h-me accent"><span class="vlist-t vlist-t2"><span class="vlist-r"><span class="vlist" style="height: 0.9579em;"><span class="" style="top: -3em;"><span class="pstrut" style="height: 3em;"></span><span style="margin-right: 0.1076em;" class="h-me mathnormal">f</span></span><span class="" style="top: -3.2634em;"><span class="pstrut" style="height: 3em;"></span><span class="accent-body" style="left: -0.0833em;"><span class="h-me">^</span></span></span></span><span class="vlist-s">​</span></span><span class="vlist-r"><span class="vlist" style="height: 0.1944em;"><span class=""></span></span></span></span></span><span class="mopen">(</span><span style="margin-right: 0.046em;" class="h-me mathnormal">ξ</span><span class="mclose">)</span><span class="mspace" style="margin-right: 0.1667em;"></span><span class="h-me"><span class="h-me mathnormal">e</span><span class="msupsub"><span class="vlist-t"><span class="vlist-r"><span class="vlist" style="height: 0.8991em;"><span class="" style="top: -3.113em; margin-right: 0.05em;"><span class="pstrut" style="height: 2.7em;"></span><span class="sizing reset-size6 size3 mtight"><span class="h-me mtight"><span class="h-me mtight">2</span><span class="h-me mathnormal mtight">πi</span><span style="margin-right: 0.046em;" class="h-me mathnormal mtight">ξ</span><span class="h-me mathnormal mtight">x</span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span><span class="mspace" style="margin-right: 0.1667em;"></span><span class="h-me mathnormal">d</span><span style="margin-right: 0.046em;" class="h-me mathnormal">ξ</span></span></span>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to style the parent element when hovering a child element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114657/how-to-style-the-parent-element-when-hovering-a-child-element)

Comment: Also duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923922/hover-on-child-should-turn-off-hover-effect-on-parent

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/erashishkatoch/6h97t12z/5/  try like this

Comment: Thanks @Ashish but I have no control over the markup. It will change randomly each time. :)

Comment: Thanks @tacoshy but the solutions assume that the markup will stay fixed. I have no control voer the markup in this case. :)

Comment: can you send me an HTML code that it looks like the second time? If the class remains the same every time then you can use this way: https://jsfiddle.net/erashishkatoch/6h97t12z/9

Comment: @Ashish I have updated the question to show how the markup might typically look.

Comment: @Ashish any element with the class `h-me` but only the element which was directly hoevered. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255642/discussion-between-ashish-and-real-noob).

Comment: I can see how to do it with the long code you have given if you really do want to highlight only the very 'inner' spans. But is there a danger that some elements may have eg padding which would be hoverable and so  highlight more. In general are you trying to highlight just one character at a time?

Comment: @AHaworth Yes, usually it would just be one character within the span tags but there might be more. I would like to highlight everything within a specific `h-me` class element I am hovering over.

Comment: Can you add a bit more of this complexity to your example HTML (e.g. giving a non-innermost span some padding) and/or change the h-me requirement to span (which is I think what your fuller example of real code needs?).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `:not()` and `:has()` css functions in a combo to get the required result. Example given below:

```css
.h-me:not(:has(.h-me)):hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<span class="h-me">
  <span class="h-me">
    <span class="h-me">
      x
    </span>
    <span class="h-me">
      y
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```