# Create a navigation list that changes its image on hover,but it doesn't work

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

**HTML**

```
<ul id="NavList">
    <li id="Home"><a href="Second.aspx"></a></li>
    <li id="About"><a href="Second.aspx"></a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**:

```
#Home {
    background: url('NavIcons/1.gif');
}
#Home a:hover {
    background: url('NavIcons\2.gif');
}
```

I am creating a navigation list that changes its image on hover, but it doesnt work.

Comment: `\2` <-- Hint...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the background change of **#Home or #About** when hovering only on `a` then you can use the following:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="NavList">
    <li id="Home"><a href="Second.aspx">1</a><div></div></li>
    <li id="About"><a href="Second.aspx">2</a><div></div></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#Home,#About {
    position:relative;
    width:70px;
    height:50px;
}
#Home div, #About div{
    position:absolute;
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JzQz.jpg');
    background-position:-20px 0px;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#Home a,#About a{
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    z-index:100;
}
#Home a:hover+div , #About a:hover+div{
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rx8G.jpg');
    background-position:-20px 0px;
}
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K7fAU/1/)

---

Got this idea from [How to style the parent element when hovering a child element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114657/how-to-style-the-parent-element-when-hovering-a-child-element) .My CSS is different but using same idea.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
#Home {
    background:  url(NavIcons/1.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

#Home:hover {
    background:  url(NavIcons/2.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

[JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M4zdG/) : But this for changing color on hover

Please check for image URL if not coming properly

Comment: This will work, but it's because Stella has a `\2` instead of a `/` for their URL.

Comment: `#Home :hover` <-- **WRONG**

Answer (score 0):

a tag will probably not be large enough to show your image. You can try this

```
#Home {
    background: url('NavIcons/1.gif');
}
#Home:hover {
    background: url('NavIcons/2.gif');
}
```

or give width and height to a.

Comment: both of them(a tag and li tag) have same width...but it does not work :(

Comment: Are image paths correct? Is NavIcons in same folder with your css or are you using inline style?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to try styling the A rather then the LI since it's just a placeholder as list item for the actual link.

```
#Home a {
    background: url('NavIcons/1.gif');
}
#Home a:hover {
    background: url('NavIcons/2.gif');
}
```