# On Hover-another DIV change size?

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a pricing table and a DIV called "base" which contains another DIV named "offer". My wish is to make that on hover one of the OFFER DIVs, that this DIV will become larger. But, I can only do that if DIV "base" gets larger first to make place to enlarge DIV "offer". Otherwise, my pricing table crashes.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114657/how-to-style-the-parent-element-when-hovering-a-child-element

Answer (score 0):

change the height of base div set to auto

```
.base{
height:auto;
}
```

then using jquery.

set the height of offer div as much as you want.

```
#('.offer.).onhover(function(){
$(this).height(value); //set value
});
```