# Div's hover effect doesn't work when I hover on the div above it

Tags: html, css, button, hover

I put a vignetting effect on my photo posts whenever you hover on them, but when I hover on the buttons on top of the photos, the vignette is gone. How do I make this work?

Here's the vignetting code I'm using:

```
.shadow {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    -webkit-transition:all.5s linear;
}

.shadow img {
    display:block;
    -webkit-transition:all.5s linear;
}

.shadow::before {
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0px #000;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0px #000;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    content:"";
    -webkit-transition:all.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:all.5s ease-out;
    transition:all.5s ease-out;
}

.shadow:hover::before {
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 250px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 250px #000;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 250px #000;
    -webkit-transition:all.8s ease-in;
    -moz-transition:all.8s ease-in;
    transition:all.8s ease-in;
}
```

And here is my **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pr85jeat/)**

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place button before image and use css selector `.button:hover+.photo .shadow::before` and `.button:hover+.button+.photo .shadow::before`

New HTML

```
<div class="entry">
    <div class="button">
        <div class="permalink"><a href=""><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/27apcde/7yjmrnwpi/pl.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <div class="reblog"><a href=""><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/27apcde/xpBmrnwv5/rb.png"></a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="photo">
        <center>
            <div class="shadow">
                <img src="https://40.media.tumblr.com/fdd926af3420367b603b70dc3fed196e/tumblr_mxrdbq86PY1r9a23uo1_500.jpg" />
            </div>
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

New CSS

```
.shadow:hover::before,
.button:hover+.photo .shadow::before,
.button:hover+.button+.photo .shadow::before{
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 250px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 250px #000;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 250px #000;
    -webkit-transition:all.8s ease-in;
    -moz-transition:all.8s ease-in;
    transition:all.8s ease-in;
}
 .button {
    position:absolute;
    background:#;
    left:21px;
    bottom:33px;
    z-index:10;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7wugpyqq/)

Comment: Some small repositioning required in the demo, compared to the original, but other than that I think this is a brilliant answer! I didn't realise CSS could operate like that.

Comment: This one actually worked, all I had to do was edit some margins. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with pure css to style a parent element by hovering the child element.

See [How to style the parent element when hovering a child element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114657/how-to-style-the-parent-element-when-hovering-a-child-element)

Or you could change your html layout to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

try to place button inside shadow

```
<div class="entry">
    <div class="photo">
        <center>
            <div class="shadow">
                <img src="https://40.media.tumblr.com/fdd926af3420367b603b70dc3fed196e/tumblr_mxrdbq86PY1r9a23uo1_500.jpg" />
                 <div class="button">
        <div class="reblog"><a href=""><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/27apcde/xpBmrnwv5/rb.png"></a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <div class="permalink"><a href=""><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/27apcde/7yjmrnwpi/pl.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
            </div>
        </center>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I also used this, but the images inside the button didn't work so I made them backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

There should be some change in your HTML structure and CSS as well.
Buttons should be inside .shadow element as you want to continue with hover of photo while hover on button too. For updates in HTML and CSS please follow my updated `(http://jsfiddle.net/smvora_4u/pr85jeat/2/)`