# CSS List Hover SubItems

Tags: html, css, web

I have a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/13v2fcjf/
It has a basic html document with lists and sublists

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1
        <ul>
            <li>Sub Item 1</li>
            <li>Sub Item 2</li>
            <li>Sub Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4
        <ul>
            <li>Child 1</li>
            <li>Child 2</li>
            <li>Child 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And I'm using the following css -

```
li:hover {
    background: #f7f7f7;
}
```

When I hover on an li item with a subitem(s), all the subitems also get highlighted. This is not desirable. I want only the list item on which the user's hovering to be highlighted. How can I achieve this ?

Also, I tried using the `:not` selector but it doesn't work.

Comment: the solution depends on the exactly desired behaviour. This is a normal behaviours as such as you don't specify a background-color for nested li's which is then transparent, so you see the background-color of the parent.

Comment: Why are you not using classes? instead of wrapping things in a or span tags i would define classes for child elements.  Have a look to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114657/how-to-style-the-parent-element-when-hovering-a-child-element and http://jsfiddle.net/k3Zdt/8/

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to set the `background` on the nested `<ul>` tag. Something like this:

```
li:hover > ul {
    background: #fff;
}
```

**Edit:** this is assuming you only want the parent `<li>` highlighted, which as @j08691 points out in the comments, might not be entirely what you're after. If you want each `<li>` to be highlighted, you might have to modify your HTML slightly to make this easier:

```
<ul>
    <li><a>Item 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Sub Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a>Sub Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a>Sub Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a>Item 4</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Child 1</a></li>
            <li><a>Child 2</a></li>
            <li><a>Child 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

By wrapping the items and sub-items in another tag - here I've just used an `<a>` tag for the sake of argument - you can target that tag to be highlighted on `:hover` without the nested tags being affected in the same way as in your original code:

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px;
}
a:hover {
    background: #f7f7f7;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/13v2fcjf/3/

Comment: This works, but it keeps the parent list item highlighted which I'm not sure the OP wants.

Comment: yeah,it keeps the parent list item highlighted. I want only one list item to be highlighted at one time

Answer (score 0):

If Ian's option doesn't work for you, a second opotion is to wrap the `<li>` contents in a span and apply the hover to that, like [**this example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/13v2fcjf/2/):

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Item 1</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span>Sub Item 1</span></li>
            <li><span>Sub Item 2</span></li>
            <li><span>Sub Item 3</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    ....
```

CSS

```
li span:hover {
    background: #f7f7f7;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

HTH,
-Ted

Answer (score 0):

This effect is just natural because the sub items are inside of the main items.

There are two options that come to my mind:

1.) Resetting the background color of the sub lists with

```
li:hover > ul {
  background-color: white;
}
```

2.) Using the `li` items as a container:

```
<li><span class="highlighted">Item</span></li>

.highlighted:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a challenge, but the following CSS works with your existing markup.  It highlights only a hovered `li`, without highlighting its parent.

The main trick is to have the CSS create new content when hovering over a nested `li`.  You can do this using the `:before` pseudo element:

```
li li:hover:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background: white;
}
```

(If you're targeting CSS3 browsers only, you can use `::before` instead of `:before`.)

This causes a nested `li` to cover up its parent `li`.  The negative z-index prevents the background from covering up any text.

Parent `li`'s need relative positioning with a z-index, and nested `li`'s need static positioning for this to work:

```
li {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

li li {
  position: static;
}
```

The other trick has been mentioned in other posts:

```
li:hover ul {
  background: white;
}
```

**Full CSS:**

```
li {
  line-height: 1.65em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

li li {
  position: static;
}

li:hover {
  background: #def;
}

li:hover ul {
  background: white;
}

li li:hover:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background: white;
}
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9tery7d/)**