# How to change the color of a link on hover of an another link?

Tags: css, html, hyperlink

Here's a code

```
 <a id="link1" href="#" >About</a>
 <a id="link2" href="#">Contact us</a>
```

I want the link1's color to be changed when link2 is hovered.
Is it possible with css?.

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: No, not possible. CSS can't go backward.

Comment: so any script for that

Comment: Yes, you can use JavaScript but CSS can't select previous siblings.

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114657/how-to-style-the-parent-element-when-hovering-a-child-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since CSS does not seem to be able to handle this, try JavaScript

```js
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("link2").onmouseover=function() {
    document.getElementById("link1").style.color="red";
  }
  document.getElementById("link2").onmouseout=function() {
    document.getElementById("link1").style.color="blue";
  }
}
```

```html
 <a id="link1" href="#" >About</a>
 <a id="link2" href="#">Contact us</a>
```

Or using siblings

```js
function prevSib(elem) {do { elem = elem.previousSibling;} while ( elem && elem.nodeType !== 1 ); return elem; }

window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("link2").onmouseover=function() {
    prevSib(this).style.color="red";
  }
  document.getElementById("link2").onmouseout=function() {
    prevSib(this).style.color="blue";
  }
}
```

```html
<a id="link1" href="#" >About</a>
<a id="link2" href="#">Contact us</a>
```

Comment: you should accept as answer if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using pure css it is not possible go backward.  You can go in cascading ways.

But, you can do it with JQuery. like:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".link2").mouseover(function(){
        $(".link1").css("color", "red");
    });
     $(".link2").mouseout(function(){
        $(".link1").css("color", "black");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="link1" class="link1" href="#" >About</a>
 <a id="link2" class="link2" href="#">Contact us</a>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

CSS can't select the previous siblings. You can use JavaScript:

```
var links = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.menu_item'));

function hover(event) {
   var pre = this.previousElementSibling,
       method = event.type === 'mouseenter' ? 'add' : 'remove'; 

   if (pre) {
       pre.classList[method]('active'); 
   }
}

links.forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('mouseenter', hover);
    el.addEventListener('mouseleave', hover);
});
```

The above code assumes that the `a` elements have class of `menu_item` and class of `active` should be added to the previous sibling of the hovered element.

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dxxbkLzt/).

Comment: Does previousElementSibling return a text node for the whitespace between the links? Also classList is quite new and unsupported in quite a few browsers. Your answer seems unnecessary complicated for what it is supposed to achieve

Comment: @mplungjan No it doesn't. It refers to the previous HTMLElement sibling. That's what `previousSibling` property does. And regarding `classList`, many browsers support the API and you can also [shim it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript to do that( `link1`'s color to be changed when `link2` is hovered ). You need to use html tag attributes like `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`.

Try this code. For changing color of `link1` when `link2` is hovered.

```
<html> 
<head>


<script>

function colorchange(){
 document.getElementById("link1").style.color="red";
}
function colorchange2(){
 document.getElementById("link1").style.color="blue";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<a id="link1" href="#" >About</a>
 <a id="link2" onmouseover="colorchange()" onmouseout="colorchange2()" href="#">Contact us</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is what are you looking for.
First you need to wrap your links inside a container like this

```
<div class='container'>
    <a id="link1" href="#" >About</a>
    <a id="link2" href="#">Contact us</a>
</div>
```

and then apply this styles

```
.container:hover a:not(:hover){
    color:red;
}
```

[css only demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/g39yyk9n/)
**UPDATE**
As I said in may comment bellow  I supposed you wanted to change the style of all unhovered links, however if you want to change only link1 when link2 is hovered , but not change style of link2 when link1 is hovered you could write you css like this
[second demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g39yyk9n/1/)

```
.container:hover a:first-child:not(:hover){
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: Interesting - it does however also colour link2 when link1 is hovered

Comment: I thought that he has a set of links and wanted to change the style of all unhovered links, anyway just for two links without having to change the style of the second when the first is hovered, js is the only solution.