# How to make a div of dynamic height and scroll when it goes out of viewport?

Tags: html, css, scroll, viewport

I know I can give a {max-height} and {overflow: auto}. But I want the max-height to be dynamic and not fixed.

Lets say that we have 2 divs on a page, if div#1 is hidden the max-height of div#2 should increase so that it occupies the maximum area before scrolling, and scrolls only when it goes out of the viewport.

Sample jsbin: http://jsbin.com/voworuveqe/edit?html,css,js,output

### Edit

Please CSS solutions only. No JS. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you should use a method like this one:

```
function('click',{

if(hide==true)
   hide =false;
   Document.getElementById(/*element*/).style="{max-height:"/*someheight*/"}"
else
   hide =true
   Document.getElementById(/*element*/).style="{max-height:"/*someotherheight*/"}"});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written up a quick example using `hover` instead of `hidden` and `height` instead of `max-height` but it should work fairly similar if you change it.

https://jsfiddle.net/6pdu6tvz/4/

The only restriction is that the element that you want to change must appear **after** the element you want to hide.

You cannot change elements before on hover as answered here: [How to style the parent element when hovering a child element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114657/how-to-style-the-parent-element-when-hovering-a-child-element). I would recommend using Javascript if you can (although you specified in your question not to).