# Highlight div preceeding div that contains focused input element

Tags: css

```
<div>highlight me</div><div><input /></div>
```

When the user puts their cursor in the input box and triggers :focus, I want to highlight the first div (apply a style to it).

non working example: https://codepen.io/samkeddy/pen/vJaqqv

Comment: parent selection does not work in CSS.

Comment: So there's no other way to do this without javascript?

Comment: Related to [How to style the parent element when hovering a child element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114657/how-to-style-the-parent-element-when-hovering-a-child-element)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Answer (score 1):

Actually previous solution is absolute but 
 If you dont want to use the javascript here you can go with little css  i have done i dont if this helps you or not but a small approach towards your question

```css
input:focus + .head{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input>
<div class="head">highlight me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function highlight()
{
var div=document.getElementById("higlightDiv");
  div.style.color="red";
}
```

```css
div{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="higlightDiv">highlight me</div><div><input type="text" onfocus="highlight();" /></div>
```

You can do it like this with javascript I guess