# Change pseudo-element style based on grandparent class

Tags: css, sass

Consider the following scss:

```
.link {
  ....

  span {
    .... 

    &:after {
      ....

      .link.active & {
        background-color: red;
      }

      .link:hover & {
        background-color: red;
      }
```

I want to change the background-color for the `span` `:after` pseudo-element when `link` is either being hovered or has the `.active` class.

What I've tried ( the code posted above ) doesnt seem to work.

Is there anything I'm missing ?

Answer (score 4):

you should try it like this scheme :

```
.link {
  span {
    &:after {
     ...
    }
  }
  &.active,
  &:hover {
    span:after {
      background-color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/92gqap5y/

Answer (score -1):

This question seems to be asked often, as [mentioned in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114657/how-to-style-the-parent-element-when-hovering-a-child-element).

They increase the size of the `link` element to be as large as the `span`. Though I would recommend moving the `:hover` selector and `.active` class to the `span` element directly.