# changing background of a field on hover (HTML, CSS)

Tags: html, css, mousehover

I have been struggling with this for a few days and cannot work out the answer:
I am trying to simply change the background of a box when on hover. I have managed to do this for the text but the rest of the box does not change.

[The link to the problem can be seen here](http://adultandchildrenspanish.com/boxcolor.php)

Here is the current code I have:
HTML

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="spanish.css"
    media="all and (min-width: 1300px)"  />

    <div class="pricebox1">
      <a href="">Conversational Spanish</a>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.pricebox1 {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 25px 0 0 400px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;

}

.pricebox1 :hover {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: red;
```

[What am I doing wrong?](http://adultandchildrenspanish.com/boxcolor.php)

Comment: `.pricebox1 :hover` should be `.pricebox1:hover ` space removed between class and :hover

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This? In the `.pricebox1 :hover {}` is not `background` but `background-color`

```css
    .pricebox1 {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 25px 0 0 400px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;

}

.pricebox1:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="pricebox1">
    <a href="">Conversational Spanish</a>
    </div>
```

And if you want to change the color of the text at the same time, simply do:

```
.pricebox1 > a:hover{
  color: red;
}
```

```css
    .pricebox1 {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 25px 0 0 400px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;

}

.pricebox1:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

.pricebox1 > a:hover{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="pricebox1">
    <a href="">Conversational Spanish</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code `.pricebox1 :hover` doesn't select the `:hover` state of the `.pricebox1`. It point to the `:hover` state of the children of the `.pricebox1`. Therefore, it doesn't change the box color.

If you want the `hover` state of a child change the background of the parent, it is not possible, as "Cascading Style Sheets only supports styling in cascading direction, not up"

So, you can use `.pricebox1:hover` to change the pricebox1 background color and `.pricebox1:hover a` to update styles of the `a` inside.

You can use a workaround solution for it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114657/how-to-style-the-parent-element-when-hovering-a-child-element)

Otherwise, you need to use `Javascript` to update the style of the parent when the child is hover, not only by `css`

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the space in `.pricebox1 :hover` - make it `.pricebox1:hover` to change the background for `.pricebox1` on hover.

You'll have to create a separate `a:hover` rule for the link then to change the text color.

Answer (score -1):

From my end, the code is working fine. The only thing you need to change is the anchor inside .pricebox1 since  have got default styling.e.g.

```
.pricebox1 a:hover{
   color: red;
}
```