# How to condition styling child by hover on parent only?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the code below when I hover on the `gray button` [the parent]

it perform some style on the **child div** `bar`

and that is what I need, **I don't want child to be hovered itself**

```css
.foo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
  margin: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.baz {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 300px;
  top: -150px;
  left: 80px;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.bar {
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://images6.alphacoders.com/411/411189.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-position: cover;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
          transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: left;
          transform-origin: left;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s ease;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s ease;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease, -webkit-transform 0.25s ease;
}
.foo:hover .bar {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
          transform: scaleX(1);
  -webkit-transform-origin: right;
          transform-origin: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div class="baz">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `.foo:hover .baz:not(:hover) .bar`, surely?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to style the parent element when hovering a child element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114657/how-to-style-the-parent-element-when-hovering-a-child-element)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol thanks... it works ✅

Comment: @user1403588 the Q you referring different , I don't like to style the parent I want to condition style on the child by hover on the parent  so child can't be hovered itself

Comment: @Paulie_D I tried to improve it...thanks

Comment: You have a lot of `-webkit-` vendor prefixes. I know that Safari has gained a reputation as 2020's Internet Explorer, but it's not that outdated, is it?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the answer you're looking for (like many, I prefer to solve CSS problems with pure CSS solutions as often as possible), but you *did* tag your question with `javascript`, so I think it's a legitimate approach to solve the issue you're facing with 3 lines of javascript:

```
const foo = document.getElementsByClassName('foo')[0];
foo.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => e.target.classList.add('hovered'), false);
foo.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => e.target.classList.remove('hovered'), false);
```

This works because the events `mouseover` and `mouseout` events are explicitly added to `foo`, rather than to its grandchild `bar` (and `bar` never visibly overlaps `foo`).

**Working Example:**

```js
const foo = document.getElementsByClassName('foo')[0];

foo.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => e.target.classList.add('hovered'), false);

foo.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => e.target.classList.remove('hovered'), false);
```

```css
.foo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
  margin: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.baz {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 300px;
  top: -150px;
  left: 80px;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.bar {
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://images6.alphacoders.com/411/411189.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-position: cover;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease;
}

.foo.hovered .bar {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div class="baz">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want the end user hover on the horizontal area (div.foo) to have the vertical area (div.baz div.bar) change but don't want the area change if the div.baz itself being hover?

Would this fix your issue?

```css
.foo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
  margin: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.baz {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 300px;
  top: -150px;
  left: 80px;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.bar {
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://images6.alphacoders.com/411/411189.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-position: cover;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
          transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: left;
          transform-origin: left;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s ease;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s ease;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease, -webkit-transform 0.25s ease;
}
.foo:hover .baz:not(:hover) .bar {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
          transform: scaleX(1);
  -webkit-transform-origin: right;
          transform-origin: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div class="baz">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```