# Select a father div from the hover of a child div

Tags: html, css

Can I select and affect the parent div, when I am on over the child div with hover? My question is if it is possible and how, in advance I apologize for my English.

```
 <div class="container">
      <div class="child-1">Wa</div>
      <div class="child-2">sup</div>
 </div>
```

```
.container{
    background: red;
}

.child-1:hover > .container{
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114657/how-to-style-the-parent-element-when-hovering-a-child-element