# How hover parent div only when input child has text?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a situation I need a border to be applied to a div when the input it contains has text, I have this:

```
<div class= "parent" >
   <input placeholder = " ">
</div>

parent:hover :not(input:placeholder-shown){
 border: 2px solid $blue-two;
}
```

but the border is applied to the input and I need it to apply to the parent div, hope you can help me, thanks

Comment: As css is not made to find parent elements the traditional solution is a JS like @ferrandusqui31 suggested. If you like to play arround a little bit with css only you you can work with a special html construct which is a workarround to produces same/similar effect with css only. If interessted see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114657/how-to-style-the-parent-element-when-hovering-a-child-element

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that you won't use for any element and put there the styles of the border:

```
.parent_border{
        border: 2px solid $blue-two;
    }
```

and then with this javascript code when you edit the input revise if has something on it and add or remove the class to the parent:

```
input.addEventListener('change', revise); // You can also use keypress event
    function revise(){
        if(input.value !== ''){
            parent.classList.add('parent_border');
        }else{
            parent.classList.remove('parent_border');
        }
    }
```