# CSS hierarchy issue

Tags: css

So I have this CSS code

```css
.body .card .card_img:hover, <- works
.body .card .card_bg_layer:hover ~ .card_img <- does not work {
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 18px black;
    max-width: 85%;
    max-height: 100%;
    left: -20px;
    top: -20px;
}

.body .card .card_img:hover ~ .card_bg_layer, <- works
.body .card .card_bg_layer:hover <- works {
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

and this is how my html looks like[image]

as u may know, I want `.card_img` to do something when `.body .card .card_bg_layer` is hovered, someone told me that css can only go down and not up, while I have no doubt that that's true but is css really that limited?

Comment: note: I did saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114657/how-to-style-the-parent-element-when-hovering-a-child-element but I do not understand what they meant

Comment: Yes, that "someone" was right

Comment: 'someone told me that css can only go down and not up' - that is correct. There are no parent selectors in CSS, to go 'up' the hierarchy you would need to use Javascript, or refractor your code.

Comment: There is no concept of 'sibling above' in CSS so the answer is 'yes, it is that limited'. Depending on what you actually want to do it's sometimes possible to look for the hover on the parent and make adjustments. Otherwise you need to reorder your HTML or use JS.

Answer (score 0):

The ~ (tilde) is used as part of the [Subsequent-sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#general-sibling-combinators), which says:

> The subsequent-sibling combinator is made of the "tilde" (U+007E, ~) character that separates two sequences of simple selectors. The elements represented by the two sequences share the same parent in the document tree and the element represented by the first sequence precedes (not necessarily immediately) the element represented by the second one.

It is important to note that the first sequence ***must precede*** the second one.

(This is not the case in your example.)