# Why isn't my opacity changing after hover without using JS?

Tags: html, css

I was trying to create a book cover that would be fully visible after being hovered upon but it isn't working

```css
#book_cover {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 25%;
  height: 71%;
  opacity: .5;
}

#book_cover a:hover {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="book_cover">
  <a href="My Link">
    <img src="https://img.wattpad.com/cover/240632149-176-k827063.jpg" alt="...." width="100%" height="100%">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are talking about changing book_cover's CSS check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114657/how-to-style-the-parent-element-when-hovering-a-child-element

Comment: Just remove the a: `#book_cover:hover {`

Comment: I think it's because `#book_cover` and `#book_cover a` opacity properties are different

Comment: also, `!important` is redundant here

Comment: and `width="100%" height="100%"` should be specified in css; in html you can specify width or height to improve your rendering performance but in pixels not percent

Comment: @mplungjan ok, but `#book_cover` is a parent element for `a` and changing `#book_cover` opacity affects `a` also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `0.5` opacity is applied to the parent. You should instead move that to the `a` selector instead:

```
#book_cover a {
  opacity: .5;
}

#book_cover a:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Remember that opacity will composite the entire element, including its children, so you cannot "override" opacity the way you think it works (as per inheritance).

Of course, if you want to control opacity on the `#book_cover` level, then do this instead:

```
#book_cover {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 25%;
  height: 71%;
  opacity: .5;
}

#book_cover:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Why not just `#book_cover:hover {`

Comment: @mplungjan Well it really depends on which element OP wants to toggle the opacity on :)

Comment: @mplungjan Updated my answer to handle the alternative

Comment: @terry, I created another element "#book_cover a{" and stored the opacity in there, and it worked, so thanks for the idea