# CSS: #id .class VS .class performance. Which is better?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'd assume that this would be faster:

```
#dialog .videoContainer { width:100px; }
```

than:

```
.videoContainer { width:100px; }
```

Of course disregarding that `.videoContainer` in the first example would only be styled under the `#dialog` tag.

Comment: I think you have it backwards... I'm not sure though. If the `#dialog` is not necessary i would not use it

Comment: @Drew - I'm assuming that parsing id's is the fastest it would then only look under #dialog no?

Comment: Google has some good tips on writing selectors: http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html#UseEfficientCSSSelectors

Answer (score 26, accepted):

CSS selectors are [matched from right to left](http://www.css-101.org/descendant-selector/go_fetch_yourself.php).

Therefore, `.videoContainer` should be "faster" than `#dialog .videoContainer` because it misses out testing for `#dialog`.

However, this is all irrelevant at best - you'll never notice the difference. For normally sized pages, the amount of time we're talking about is so insignificant as to be nonexistent.

Here's a relevant answer by an expert that you should read: [Why do browsers match CSS selectors from right to left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797014/css-selectors-parsed-right-to-left-why)