# Selector Performance - 'E#id' vs '#id' - in CSS and jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, performance, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

When using selectors in CSS and in jQuery, are there any efficiency differences between using`'E#id'` and `#id`, where E is any HTML element? If yes, does it only apply to certain layout engines and/or Javascript engines?

Comment: Some of the new (and I mean bleeding-edge new) browsers have CSS performance inspectors that let you test for yourself.

Comment: In my opinion the only reason to use `'E#id'` is if you only want to select an element with that id _if_ it is of the right type, though I can't really think of many real world examples where there wouldn't be a better way to do it anyway. (Remembering that id should be unique so this should not be used to distinguish between different elements on the same page.)

Comment: An `id` should only occur once in the document so you shouldn't need the element name part of that selector.

Comment: Actually `E#id` is considered to be ( if not bad , then ) avoidable practice. As for JQuery, if f care about performance , then instead of `$('#foo')` you should do `document.getElementById('foo')`.

Comment: The accepted answer is wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers read the selectors right to left so there is little to be gained by prefixing anything before the id; it is redundant at that point. Source:
[Writing Efficient CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Writing_Efficient_CSS) from Mozilla

Here's a [real world example](http://stevesouders.com/efws/css-selectors/csscreate.php) to test it for yourself. TL:DR; it doesn't seem to matter enough to make a difference.

Relevant further reading from a previous [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797014/css-selectors-parsed-right-to-left-why)

Comment: Actually, `E#id` has higher specificity than `#id`. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x7Ahx/)

Comment: @bookcasey That isn't relevant to the question. The OP is only interested in the speed differences between the two selectors as far as javascript and selector engines are concerned..

Answer (score 0):

1) It's considered that using ID's for CSS is not a good practice. It should be used when manipulating content through javascript.

2) Over qualifying CSS selector with tag name ul.top-nav or ul#top-nav will only increase overhead on browser since it has to match both the tag & class/ID. Hence, avoid over-qualifying the selector.