# Fastest CSS selector?

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors

Given that I have a popup, with ID "popup" and in it two buttons, one on the left and one on the right side, with class "popupbutton", which of these css rules is most efficient:

```
#popup a.popupbutton

#popup .popupbutton

a.popupbutton

.popupbutton
```

Comment: What are you trying to select?

Comment: Idk if you need to be that concerned about speed with css, how many of these are you styling?

Comment: Is this being downvoted because people think it is irrelevant? Optimizing CSS selectors is almost certainly a waste of time, but a question can be interesting per se.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.popupbutton
```

The class will be quicker. But when you get down to it, you're saving yourself something like 20-50ms (which may or may not matter).

There's a pretty good test done you can read about here that looks at the difference in css selector speed across multiple browsers: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/03/10/performance-impact-of-css-selectors/

> The average slowdown across all browsers is 50 ms, and if we look at the big ones (IE 6&7, FF3), the average delta is just 20 ms. For 70% or more of today’s users, improving these CSS selectors would only make a 20 ms improvement.

As you can see from the article, the difference of selector speed is pretty low and these tests were against pretty robust DOM examples.

Comment: Agreed! The efficiency of CSS selectors will only matter *at all* when selecting large sets of elements. Consider it a micro-enhancement, and don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

`.popupbutton` is the fastest selector, check google [PageSpeed tips](http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html#UseEfficientCSSSelectors) on CSS rendering

Comment: Perhaps not for the reason you might think, though. This comes entirely from the fact that selectors are applied right-to-left.

Comment: That's it, which happens in most cases, heres a more detailed answer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797014/css-selectors-parsed-right-to-left-why

Answer (score 1):

`.popupbutton` is the fastest.
But keep in mind that `a.popupbutton` is not the same as `.popupbutton`. They will do the same thing most of the time but consider this exception:

```
a:link { color: red; }
.popupbutton { color: green; } /* Won't work */
a.popupbutton { color: green; } /* Will work */
```