# Adding a </br> every second list item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a list in which I need to had a break for every two elements:

Original:

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Need:

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</br>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9uksT/

Is this possible with Jquery?

**EDIT: Oh wow sorry for the question. I am also open to using CSS. I just need to have a space between every 2 pairs of list items**

Comment: That's invalid HTML... The `<br>` tag is not a closing tag, and `<ul>` can only contain `<li>`, not `<br>`.

Comment: Your title says every second item, but your description says every two elements, these are different things. Please clarify. Not my downvote btw

Comment: Yes, it is possible with jquery. No guarantees what the browser will do with it though.

Comment: Bad idea as the only valid chid of <ul> is <li>

Comment: You'd be better off giving the second list item a class with a margin-bottom.

Comment: Why don't you add a CSS style to set the margin (or padding) you need?

Comment: what about using CSS ?

Comment: I would say something like this works:
$("li:nth-child(3n+1)").css("margin-bottom", "10");

Comment: Add a `li` with a `br` element http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Bm9rH/1/

Comment: or use a margin-bottom http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Bm9rH/2/ - ie < 9 not supported

Comment: +1 as the downvotes are a little harsh when the overall aim was valid, even if the specific suggestion of BRs between LIs was invalid.

Comment: Yea, I'm completely up for using CSS, I just thought I needed a break,  sorry I didn't know better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't abuse `<br>` tags this way. Give every second element a wider bottom margin using CSS:

```
.root ul li:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/9uksT/3/

That said, I would replace your `<ul>` sub-list with a definition list, which is more semantically correct in this case:

```
.root dl {
    margin: 0 0 0 2em;
}
.root dl dd {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/E7gAA/

Comment: [But only use this in CSS if you're targeting IE >= 9.](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child)

Comment: @rid [There are solutions for that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577674/how-to-make-internet-explorer-8-to-support-nth-child-css-element).

Comment: Thanks. I don't know what was so unclear about my question but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As described that would be invalid HTML, but you can add `<br/>&nbsp;` inside the end of every second `<li>` element

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/9uksT/2/

```
$('ul:not(.root) li:odd').append("<br/>&nbsp;");
```

### Update:

As the question has now changed, to include CSS, I would not do it this way, but would use a selector to set a style on the LIs (as Arun P Johny shows). e.g.

```
$('ul:not(.root) li:odd').addClass('second')
```

This works on all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class and jQuery to assign the class to the right elements

```
.menu-vertical li.even{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

then

```
$('.menu-vertical > ul li:nth-child(2n)').addClass('even')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Bm9rH/)

Note: As I shown in the comments it can be done using [nth-child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child), but it is not supported by [IE < 9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child#Browser_compatibility)