# Is there a reason why CSS pseudo-element[non-standard] cannot be combined with Chrome, while Firefox accepts them without a problem?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

case example

> doesn't work on Chrome, Fine for Firefox

```css
#my-slider {
  width              : 400px;
  margin             : 1em;
  -webkit-appearance : none;
  height             : 8px;
  border-radius      : 4px;
  background-color   : teal;
  }
#my-slider::-webkit-slider-thumb,
#my-slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance : none;
  -moz-appearance    : none;
  width              : 30px;
  height             : 30px;
  border-radius      : 15px;
  border             : none;
  background-color   : orange;
  overflow           : visible;
  cursor             : pointer;
  }
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" id="my-slider">
```

> fine for both

```css
#my-slider {
  width              : 400px;
  margin             : 1em;
  -webkit-appearance : none;
  height             : 8px;
  border-radius      : 4px;
  background-color   : teal;
  }
#my-slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance : none;
  width              : 30px;
  height             : 30px;
  border-radius      : 15px;
  border             : none;
  background-color   : orange;
  overflow           : visible;
  cursor             : pointer;
  }
#my-slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  -moz-appearance    : none;
  width              : 30px;
  height             : 30px;
  border-radius      : 15px;
  border             : none;
  background-color   : orange;
  overflow           : visible;
  cursor             : pointer;
  }
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" id="my-slider">
```

Or is it "just a Bugg" ?

Comment: Firefox recognize both selector but chrome doesn't recognize the one of firefox making all the rule invalid. Always use the second snippet

Answer (score 1):

It's a CSS [edge case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_case) (maybe not present in all browsers), when Chrome browser can't decode/recognize the first selector (therefore consider it as **invalid**), it response is to ignore the whole rule including the other selectors (even if they are valid), **more specifically** it stops parsing and doesn't even look if they are valid or not.

[The same behaviour is present on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21856652/10797718), so technically it's not truly a bug.

So your second snippet is the way to go when you want to deal with non-standard pseudo-element(s).

Comment: Your explanation seems to me to be well founded : css remains an uncompromising language.. it's a shame, in the case presented here it should more simply be a supernumerary selector to ignore, because  there is no syntactic error here ... which is precisely the principle used by Firefox.