# Even / odd css change using jquery event in sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have set of divs built in php based on the data I load in, and I use sortable for the users to be able to change to order and save it. 
To make it more comfortable to use I'd like every second div in set to be of different format.
This code works when I move one "even" div to another "even" position, otherwise when I place "even" div to where "odd" one is it starts to color all between them as "odd".

Code:

```
$( ".droppable" ).sortable({
  update: function( ) {
    $(".draggable:nth-child(even)").addClass("even");
    $(".draggable:nth-child(odd)").addClass("odd");
  }
});
```

What do I do wrong?
Cheers for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What did I do wrong?

### You used jQuery.

Use CSS:

```
.draggable:nth-child(even) {
    background: #eee; /* Or whatever you want */
}
```

Comment: What browser? Jsfiddle?

Comment: It should be on even, not odd. Not your mistake, you couldn't know that I have every even one grey :)

Comment: But I know nth-child doesn't work on IE8, is there a way to make it work there? This is the reason I use jquery for this on every other structure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577674/how-to-make-internet-explorer-8-to-support-nth-child-css-element

Comment: Mate thanks for you help, this thing sorted me out. Thanks for keepin it awesome here. <3

Answer (score 1):

I would use CSS pseudo-classes

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/UAcC7/737/

```
li:nth-child(odd) {
    color: green;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of the addclass statements and check if it makes a difference.