# DIV color not displaying properly in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, oracle-apex

I am developing Application in `ORACLE APEX` with custom theme.

application run perfectly in all browser except IE, IE doesn't show color properly as I was expecting.

this result comes from my chrome browser.
[image]

now in Internet Explorer 8 (IE8) all this messed up, the color effect is not displaying properly.
[image]

Here is my `CSS` for `1,2,3,4 <div>`

```
.top-tabs .tab:nth-child(1),.head1 .region-header {
   background-color: #014fa2;
}

.top-tabs .tab:nth-child(2),.head2 .region-header {
   background-color: #1e69b9;
}

.top-tabs .tab:nth-child(3),.head3 .region-header {
   background-color: #3481d2;
}

.top-tabs .tab:nth-child(4),.head4 .region-header {
   background-color: #58a1f0;
}
```

Here is my `HTML`

```
<ul class="top-tabs">
    <li class="tab">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="top-tab-nr">1</div>
        <div class="top-tab-label">Admission<br>Application</div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="tab">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="top-tab-nr">2</div>
        <div class="top-tab-label">Pay<br>Application Fee</div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="tab">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="top-tab-nr">3</div>
        <div class="top-tab-label">Submit<br>Required Documents</div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="tab">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="top-tab-nr">4</div>
        <div class="top-tab-label">Sign up<br>Information</div>
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

any help / guideline to overcome from this ??

Comment: Don't think IE8 supports `nth-child` selector

Comment: Well, since it looks like an whole other page ( no steps completed and so on ), my first guess would be that you missed an include to an CSS file? Maybe inside the `!--[if IE....` stuff?

Comment: Since it's not supported in `IE8`, maybe the `jQuery` version will be an alternative `$(".tab:nth-child(1n)")`.

Comment: @pete - what would be the possible soulution?

Comment: [Try this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577674/how-to-make-internet-explorer-8-to-support-nth-child-css-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No JavaScript necessary...

**Option A**
Give each list item a class, the same way you did the headers.

**Option B**
Use the `+` ([adjacent sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)) selector. Like this:

```
.top-tabs .tab:first-child,.head1 .region-header {
   background-color: #014fa2;
}

.top-tabs .tab:first-child + .tab,.head2 .region-header {
   background-color: #1e69b9;
}

.top-tabs .tab:first-child + .tab + .tab,.head3 .region-header {
   background-color: #3481d2;
}

.top-tabs .tab:first-child + .tab + .tab + .tab,.head4 .region-header {
   background-color: #58a1f0;
}
```

Try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/3q9cD/

Comment: Yes, as long as you use a `doctype`. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors#Browser_compatibility