# Alternate color css for table not apply

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
 function Foo(id) {
         if (document.getElementByTagName) {
             var $rows = $('#' + id + ' tr : not(:hidden)');
             for (var i = 0; i < $rows.length; i++) {
                 if (i % 2 == 0)

                 $rows[i].className = "even";
                 else $rows[i].className = "odd";
             }
         }

     }
```

this is my function, I get it working in my code but not on this fiddle, also, If I able to apply the `Foo method` in tab 1. It will not display on tab2(vice versa). My question is how can I apply `Foo()` on both table residing in different tab simultaneously.

See this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/042xL68s/1/) for example. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Ideal solution: CSS**

What about removing all that Javascript and replacing the CSS by this:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color : gray;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color : white;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/042xL68s/2/)

More info about the power of `nth-child` can be found on [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/). Note that this solution doesn't work in IE8, but personally I would find that acceptable. After all it's just a cosmetic aid, and users of such an old browser can either use your site without it, or upgrade their browser.

**Fixing your Javascript**

Your Javascript solution could work as well, by the way, but it has some errors. First of all `if (document.getElementByTagName)` just checks whether the function `getElementByTagName` exists, while I think you planned on executing it to get the table or the rows.

It works better like this:

```
 function Foo(id) {
     var $rows = $('#' + id + ' tr');
     for (var i = 0; i < $rows.length; i++) {
         if (i % 2 == 0)
             $rows[i].className = "even";
         else $rows[i].className = "odd";
     }
 }
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/042xL68s/6/)

**Other issues left to solve in Javascript**

I removed the `:not(:hidden)` part, because that is (another) issue that prevents this code to work for the second tabsheet. If you need this because you want to be able to show or hide rows, you have to take a couple of things into account:

- There should be no spaces in that selector, otherwise you'll be selecting the cells and the result will be a checker board look, so it should be `tr:not(:hidden)`.
- If you are coloring the cells, it won't work for the second tab, because that tab is hidden by the time you call Foo. To solve this, you can reverse the calls to `Foo` and to `$.tabs`. That way, all tabs will still be visible when you call `Foo`.

Code:

```
 $(function () {
   Foo("searchMe1"); // This first
   Foo("searchMe2");
   $("#tabs").tabs(); // Then this.
```

- You will bump into another problem if you are dynamically going to hide rows. It will mess up your coloring. You would have to call Foo every time you do to re-apply the classes. That also means that Foo needs to remove the previously assigned classes as well, otherwise you'll have both. This might need some work. :)

Note that all these problems won't exist with the CSS solution. Hidden rows are just not taken into account. See for instance [THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/042xL68s/7/) where Captain America is hidden.

Comment: Apart from the CSS solution, I also addressed the issues in you Javascript, although the end conclusion is that CSS really is the best approach here.

Comment: Thanks sir,unfortunately,I have to work it in IE8. But sir, i message you later If i do have question.Thanks.

Comment: what version of IE is this css wull work(if there is)?

Comment: Here is another question about IE 8 support. It suggests Selectivizr, a Javascript work-around, and another answer shows a trick that might also be helpful. Maybe it's of use to you: [How to make Internet Explorer 8 to support nth child() CSS element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577674/how-to-make-internet-explorer-8-to-support-nth-child-css-element)