# nth-child(2n) not supported by ie8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors

I have this css witch works perfectly with all browser exept ie8
this is my css

```
.team-list.list2:nth-child(2n) li {
        margin: 0 0 0 56px;
    }

.team-list:nth-child(2n) {
    margin: 0 -100px 0 -150px;
}

    .team-list:nth-child(2n) li {
        margin: -101px 0 0 73px;
    }
```

how to make it compatible with ie8

I tried to add selectvizir but it does not work i know that there a solution with jquery but i am so novice in jquery so could you help me find solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make Internet Explorer 8 to support nth child() CSS element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577674/how-to-make-internet-explorer-8-to-support-nth-child-css-element)

Comment: I saw it and  tried  it but no result

Comment: why is selectvizir not working, can you show how you add it?

Comment: I download it from here : http://selectivizr.com/ and add this script <script type="text/javascript" src="[JS library]"></script>
<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="selectivizr.js"></script>
  <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="[fallback css]" /></noscript>
<![endif]-->   i changed of course the path

Answer (score 0):

for IE8 you could add the following script and it should perform like any modern SANE browser :)

```
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

you check out other IE scripts [here](https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/).

Comment: did you try for `nth-child(even)`?

Comment: how do i use it ? instead of .team-list.list2:nth-child(2n) li i put .team-list.list2:nth-child(even)?

Comment: yes, also check the the script you use is `IE9.js` that is supposed to support version 5.5 up to version 8