# Does removing unneeded javascript and css includes lighten the web page load times?

Tags: javascript, css, web

We have a web application with a common header file for all pages. We want to reduce the page load times. We are thinking of having separate headers for different pages, depending on each page's specific javascript and css needs. Will that make any difference in the load time, or not (since they are cached by the browser)?

Comment: When you say different headers what CMS are you talking about?

Comment: It's a custom java web application built with Struts tiles. It has a common header include with all js and css files.

Comment: Wait, are you asking about removing stuff you never use, or consolidating stuff you *do* use into fewer files?  The "unneeded" in your title seems a bit misleading.

Comment: The "unneeded" refers to stuff that are never used in some pages, but are however included in all pages as they all have a common header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Yes. Absolutely.***

Many folks clear their cache or even turn it off completely (like me).

Even if the unneeded JavaScript is cached it is still run by the browser.

Check out http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/.

This tool tests the load time of that page so you can analyze it and find bottlenecks in load time.

When you say different headers what CMS are you talking about? Most CMSs allow you to add additional page head data, JS or CSS, in hooks or ugh placeholders.

Comment: So if each page has its own js/css includes where is it better to place them within the page's body? Is it better to place them at the bottom of each page instead of having them within the header?

Comment: @spyk I like JS at the bottom. CSS, whether `<link>` or `<style>` have to be in the `head`. What type of CMS are you using?

Comment: It's not a CMS but a custom java webapp (see above). Our concern is that it increases the complexity, as we need to maintain different header files for different pages.

Comment: Have the header file end with the `<head>` tag unclosed and close it in each page layout. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, but I don't think it is a good idea as it messes a bit with the structure of our includes.

Comment: It's possible to simulate "include" sections somewhat like ASP.NET master pages. This is for PHP, but I'm sure it could be adapted for java http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/creating-an-html-friendly-template-system-using-phps-output-buffering/ I've used this specific technique in PHP before and it does really work well.

Answer (score 1):

People have addressed the JS issues already.

CSS includes can also impact page speed noticeably. CSS rules are matched right to left by browsers, which is very different to how most people think about writing their rules. Given a complicated enough layout, CSS optimizations could improve your rendering times significantly.

http://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/

http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm#CSS_parsing

[Why do browsers match CSS selectors from right to left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797014/css-selectors-parsed-right-to-left-why)

Comment: +1 good point. Rerdless of caching browsers still execute / parse the JS and CSS.

Comment: I will add that you must balance between including some measure of unnecessary code/css in your files, and having too many http requests. For example: You may only need a few functions from JQuery in a given page. That does **not** mean getting obsessive about only loading the absolute necessities and splitting JQuery across multiple files. I generally have "core" files (both js and css) that get included everywhere, and only things that   may only get used once in an application get their own include. HTTP requests will slow you down **way** faster than a bit of code bloat

Comment: Yes, I have found that to be true. Which is why I am obsessive about my sprites. http://www.vbgov.com/siteassets/images/layout/sprite.png