# CSS selected tag higher than class

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        input[type='text'], select {
            background: blue
        }

        .error {
            background: red
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" class="error"/>
<select class="error">
    <option>non-sense</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

If the class `.error` has background red than it must be red. Even if `input[type="text"]` has a blue background. Tested in IE and GC.

Answer (score 5):

The reason for the problem you're seeing, is that `input[type=text]` is more specific than `.error`, so it will override it. Use a more specific selector:

```
input.error
```

Or if you want to really be safe:

```
input[type=text].error
```

More information about **[CSS specificity, and how it's calculated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12743702/871050)**

---

Another approach would be to keep the current selector, but add the `!important` keyword on the rule:

```
.error { background: red !important; }
```

That would instantly make it override **any other rules matched for the element**. Beware, it's a very powerful tool, and may lead to unexpected results in the future.

Comment: So now what, based on my answer you improve your own? Bad!

Comment: What if he uses `.error` on any number of tags, or unknown tags for that matter?

Comment: You could improve the answer by including a reference to CSS specificity, so that OP could get some clue as to what is "more specific" in this context.

Comment: @kontur then the style will apply. Is that a bad thing? It wasn't specified that it should apply only to one instance.

Comment: Any other rule not having `!important` you wanted to say I guess. Also beware of `style=""` attributes.

Comment: @Caelea: Your answer raised a possible solution. But you did not state the dangers of it in the long run. You just gave a solution and said "use this" without explaining. http://i2.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/420/481/35a.jpg

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Stop posting pictures please, it's not yet that time of day. I also think you already made your argument, no need to stress it. A little helpful edit in somebodies other question is often more straight to the point.

Comment: I wanted to set a default style for all text inputs without styling checkboxes or radios. The .error is a common class if some required fields don't have a proper value. The normal hierachy says: tags < classes < ids < style. But a more specific tag seems to have a higher priority than a class ( id and style not tested yet :) )

Comment: @ortreum: 2 classes > 1 class. 1 ID > 200 classes. That's how the specificity goes. `[atrribute=selectors]` == `.class` in that manner. If you want a more specific selector, you can simply add the `form` element before the selector, to add an additional point to the "elements", which changes the specificity in your favor :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `.error { background: red !important }`

Be aware of the limitations this has, please see: [**!important rules (CSS 2.1 Section 6.4.2)**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules)

Comment: Using `!important` so lightly will make your code a real headache in the long run. Beware!

Comment: @MadaraUchiha so does stiling your css in the html rather than a separate file. I'm trying to solve his problem not learn him how to proper code his entire site

Comment: @Caelea: True, but I can assume that for the sake of the question he prepared this snippet for us to see, so it can all be in one place. A reproducible test-case. Encouraging him to use `!important` on such a petty matter, is actively encouraging bad-practice.

Comment: @Caelea: It's okay to leave the context of the concrete question and give a more general advice that is of use for further users, too. However, no need for so many downvotes if you would leave a little note about the limitations of that approach in my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<html>
   <head>
       <style>

           input[type='text'], select { background: blue }
           .error { background: red; }
           input.error { background: red; }

       </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" class="error" />
        <select class="error">
            <option>non-sense</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: that's working. but needless to say: css is a nightmare if you don't know every little its-not-a-bug-its-a-feature-feature D: