# speed of declaring element with class name vs. class name

Tags: css

Will it work faster if I define class with

```
input.classname
```

or if I only define

```
.classname
```

in CSS?

Comment: You could try and make a benchmark. Other than that, for the flexibility I believe its better to use `.classname` rather than `element.classname` so you can apply the class on different element. However in some cases you may want to style all the elements in the same way, but one slightly different. The `element.classname` can come in handy. But that could also be done using an other class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically yes, there is a ***very*** slight difference in speed. But you don't need to worry about CSS matching speed. It's microseconds (as in *millionths* of a second).

What you should worry about is **specificity**.

See my **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743458/efficient-algorithm-to-compare-specificity-of-css-rules/12743702#12743702)** here.

Answer (score 0):

No, CSS rules are matched right to left. That is to say, they will have the same performance.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers read CSS selectors from right to left. So I assume that only the classname is faster.
I would not tag-qualify classes despite you wanted to have some styling be different depending on the element.