# Improve performance of CSS class switch

Tags: css, performance, browser, user-interface, css-selectors

I have a list of items that can be displayed in **"grid or list"** mode.

This is implemented in HTML this way :

```
<!-- List mode -->
<div class="items list">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
<!-- Grid mode -->
<div class="items grid">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

When the user clicks a button, I just switch between the `grid/list` CSS classes using jQuery. In my stylesheets I'm styling the `.items.grid > ul` / `.items.list > ul`, sometimes hiding sub elements in `grid` mode, something like :

```
.items.grid .hidden-grid {
    display: none;
}

.items.grid ul li {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}
```

The number of elements displayed in the list can vary, and is loaded via "infinite scroll" until there are remaining items.

This is working fairly good, **but it starts being slow when the number of elements grows.** I was expecting this to be instantaneous, but it blocks the browser.

**What could I do to make it faster ?**

The looks related to the browser having to render the elements again.

Could this be related to the CSS structure ?

Comment: Why not just use the ul's themself and get rid of the div's around them?

Comment: Does this make a big difference ?

Comment: Anything will make a difference, `less is more`. :)

Comment: Are you making a class change on the outer div, or are you showing list and hiding grid, and vice versa?

Comment: Most "infinite scroll" type paging only keep a subset of elements on the page at once.   Take a look at https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid for an idea of a data loader.  Sadly, there's not much documentation, but you can get the idea of what to do with your elements

Comment: Of course I'm only switching CSS classes ! :-)

Comment: @Kirean > Do you think this is related to infinite scroll ?

Comment: @mexique1 its related to the number of elements you have on the page.  You are correct in thinking that its because the browser has to rerender everything.  Since less is more, as Tom pointed out, having fewer elements on the screen will make the switch more responsive.  To that end, most infinite scroll type things will remove elements if they get too high in the list and are thus not visible.  This keeps the DOM small, and responsive

Comment: @Kirean ok, but this means the plugin has to manage up/down loading ? This looks complicated and I'm afraid this won't fit the requirements

Comment: This _really_ looks related to CSS selectors performance, looking in this direction..

Comment: There is no such thing as "CSS structure", only HTML/DOM structure. Also what Kirean said.

Comment: Thank you guys, I got it. Not really CSS structure, but read below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually related to CSS selectors and the way the browser parses them to render the page, or render elements again.

It is very logical when you know, but **browsers evaluate CSS selectors from right to left**, starting from the element they will finally have to style. Even CSS IDs don't make a big difference. This is different from the jQuery way of thinking.

[Writing efficient CSS selectors](http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/)

[Optimize browser rendering](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rendering)

[Why do browsers match CSS selectors from right to left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797014/why-do-browsers-match-css-selectors-from-right-to-left)

So I replaced element selectors by classes selectors, remove deep selectors, and the difference is noticeable.

**HTML**

```
<div class="items">
    <ul class="grid">
        <li class="item>...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.grid .item {
    ...
}

.grid .hidden-grid {
    display: none !important;
}

.list .item .description {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't think jQuery thinks very differently in selectors without IDs. Also, you didn't *just* change your selectors. You also had to change your markup to accommodate the changes that you made to your selectors as well. So it's a little bit of both.

Comment: It is, because in JavaScript, an element with an ID should be unique in the page, and only the first will be matched, but CSS doesn't care, you can have several elements with same CSS ID.