# Why are selectors such as a[title="home"] slower than using class?

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors

I have been reading a lot of CSS performance articles, such as;

- [Efficiently Rendering CSS](http://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/)
- [Writing efficient CSS selectors](http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/)
- [Writing efficient CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FWriting_Efficient_CSS)

I get why selectors like this are bad

```
#social a {
}
```

As the browser will read *a* first, then is forced to loop through all the *<a>* tags in the page.

But why is a selector such as *a[title="home"]* slower than using a *class*?

I assume that the browser creates some sort of an index to be able to figure out what elements have a certain class (Correct?).

But shouldn't browsers also have indexed up what elements have a certain attribute? (such as *title*)?

**My question is**; why is the CSS / element look up way slower when using selectors such as *a[title="home"]* compared to using a  *class*? What or how does the browser act in order that the result is so much slower?

Comment: "But shouldn't browsers also have indexed up what elements have a certain attribute?" -- do you think, this makes sense? A class says something like "Hey, I am of this type, anybody can do something with me!" while a placeholder attribute just says "Yo, browser, render me this way, and then forget about me". And since indexing takes some time, I think browsers decide to index just the first kind of attributes.

Comment: FYI, the term "universal selector" specifically refers to the `*` selector. `a[title="home"]` is not a universal selector; `[title="home"]` without the `a`, on the other hand, you could say makes use of an *implicit* universal selector because it's equivalent to `*[title="home"]`.

Comment: Also, "As the browser will read a first, then is forced to loop through all the <a> tags in the page." This isn't how mainstream browsers behave; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797014/why-do-browsers-match-css-selectors-from-right-to-left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browser implementors optimize the most common cases. Since classes are used very frequently to match styles, they must implement this as efficiently as they can. When they load in CSS, they index the classes to make this possible.

Since random selectors like `title="home"` are not used very frequently, they can get away with implementing them using simpler searches. It won't have as much impact on performance, because it will rarely be used.

Classes also require special treatment in the browser, because an element may have multiple classes, e.g. `class="foo bar baz"`. When parsing the document, the browser needs to split this up so that it can match any of them against CSS selectors.

Comment: So your answer is basically, modern browsers create indexes for classes, but not for any other attributes. Hence using any other attribute than the class attribute will there by be slower?

Comment: Yes. Classes and IDs are intended for use in selectors, so they've optimized for that use.

Comment: Note that for this reason, using an attribute selector to match by the `class` attribute is not optimized. (Besides, if you're using attribute selectors to match class names, you're probably trying to match using special criteria that can't be achieved with a class selector anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

[Benchmark](https://github.com/truetone/css-selector-benchmarking)

**Conclusions**

*In most cases 'attribute selector with unknown attribute, e.g. [a="b"]' and 'attribute selector with known attribute, e.g. [title="a"]' showed up in the '3 Worst' category. It's safe to say you should avoid those selectors.*

Comment: Why did you test such old browser versions?

Comment: @Barmar: He wasn't the one who wrote these tests. Steve Souders did. The article where the chart is taken from was written 4 years ago.

Comment: Neither of the test pages uses selectors like `a[title="home"]`.

Comment: @BoltClock Yeah, I noticed that after I commented. Ancient benchmarks are hardly relevant to current browsers.

Comment: The first paragraph of the Conclusion of that page confirms what the OP wrote: _'attribute selector with known attribute, e.g. [title="a"]' showed up in the '3 Worst' category._