# In what order are jQuery selectors executed?

Tags: jquery

If I have following jQuery selector specified :

`$("div#myDivId .myClass")`

What is the exact selection order? Will this first select a div with an ID `myDivId` and then find all elements with `myClass` inside it or first select all elements with `myClass` and then filter out rest which are not inside `myDivId`.

Comment: Why don't you [take a peek at the unminified source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) and check it out?

Comment: The general question in your title depends on whether jQuery is able to pass the string to _querySelectorAll()_ or not, which will depend on whether you've used jQuery custom selectors (and on whether the browser even supports _querySelectorAll(),_ etc.).

Comment: @MartyWallace Tried doing that but got lost. If I don't get an answer will do that again. Thanks.

Comment: @nnnnnn : For now I am not interested in custom selectors, I just care about available selectors. Thanks.

Comment: I don't mean custom selectors in the sense of ones that _you_ define, I mean selectors that are "available" by default in jQuery but not part of the CSS specification, like the [`:input` selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/).

Comment: [This](http://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/) helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sizzle API (that used by jQuery) uses "right-to-left" order of selector's tokens "execution".

For the modern browsers that support QSA (native querySelectorAll function) Sizzle will actually delegate the work to it that also "right-to-left".

Here is performance comparison: [Sizzle vs. QSA](http://jsperf.com/sizzle-scoped-vs-qsa), also
I've create sample for your case: http://jsperf.com/does-order-of-selectros-matters

Another question is **why** they are "right-to-left"? See here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797014/why-do-browsers-match-css-selectors-from-right-to-left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797014/why-do-browsers-match-css-selectors-from-right-to-left#)