# Most specific CSS selector for a class

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

I have a CSS class, let's call it `myclass`

```
.myclass {
  background-color: 'green';
}
```

that is being added dynamically to the elements on the page. This works well, but when there is more specific selector, for example: `input[type='text']` , it's `background-color` property is used. Now, I need to write more specific selector, although I don't know on which element in the DOM this class will be added, so that will overwrite all other selectors on that element. Maybe I could start with something like this :

```
html body .myclass {
   background-color: 'green';
}
```

or there is a better way ?

Comment: try `.myclass {
  background-color: 'green' !important;
}`

Comment: My answer here is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19399881/1317805

Comment: @JamesDonnelly , I can't use ID's, but repeating css class selector really seems interesting, I'll try that!

Comment: It's wrong syntax `background-color: 'green'` by the way, it must be without the quotes, and this tool can be quite useful - http://josh.github.io/css-explain/ one more link - http://csswizardry.com/2014/07/hacks-for-dealing-with-specificity/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading about [selector specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Wrapping it around an (for example) ID would increase the priority for that element.

```
#myid .myclass{ 
    background: green; 
}
```

Or you could specify .myclass to an element.

```
div.myclass  {}
```

Comment: as I said, I don't know on which specific DOM element this class will be added, so I can't use id of a parent.

Comment: You could specify it to a set element. If you use div then div.myclass