# JQuery selector performace and comparesion issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

All three operation are performing same thing.
can anyone explain the reason for different performance?

```
console.time('first');
for(guid in ALLGUID){   
   $('.'+guid).find('.cell-taskname').find('.cell-text').text()
}
console.timeEnd('first');

console.time('second');
for(guid in ALLGUID){
 $('.'+guid).find('.cell-taskname .cell-text').text()
}
console.timeEnd('second');

console.time('third');
for(guid in ALLGUID){
 $('.'+guid+' .cell-taskname .cell-text').text()
}
console.timeEnd('third');
```

**first:  ~3500.000ms**

**second:  ~3700.000ms**

**third:  ~38000.000ms** (*yes it is 38 second.*)

**Scenario Explanation**: I have Huge table and I am iterating over all table rows. here Guid is unique key and class name of table row. cell-taskname is div inside every first column of table-row and .cell-text is span containing text.

Comment: I can't explain the performance difference here, but if the GUID is a unique key, why do you use it as a class name rather than as an element id? Selecting by id is much faster than selecting by class.

Comment: And not by just a little bit: http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-id-vs-queryselector-class (you can't even see the bars for the class selector, it's so overwhelmed by `getElementById`).

Comment: @pdw Above question is my problem its just an attempt to explain my problem. its Extremely simplified version of my problem. btw I am using ID selector. TY

Comment: I was aware of this fact ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It all has to do with the fact that selectors are processed *right-to-left*.

In your first and second examples, the main search of the DOM is only for the elements with the given GUID class. Then, you only search *within* those elements for the cells.

But in your last example, with a single selector, the engine does this:

1. Make a list of all `.cell-text` elements.
2. Remove ones that don't have an ancestor matching `.cell-taskname` from the list.
3. Remove any remaining ones that don't have an ancestor matching `.<your-guid-here>` from the list.

You can see how that takes a bit longer, if there are lots of `.cell-text` elements and only a few `.<your-guid-here>` elements. You've said that the `.<your-guid-here>` element is unique (a single row in a massive table), so the performance difference makes sense here.

More on right-to-left matching in [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797014/why-do-browsers-match-css-selectors-from-right-to-left).

Answer (score 3):

lets say you have 100 rows with GUIDs, with each 100 .cell-taskname in them, with each 100 .cell-text in them.

- 100 GUIDS
- 10000 .cell-taskname
- 1000000 .cell-text

selectors are done right to left, so if you would do the 3rd example:

```
select all .cell-text (1m)
eliminate those that don't an ancestor .cell-taskname (still 1m)
eliminate those that don't have a higher ancestor of .guid (10k)
```

while if you do the first one:

```
select all .guid (1)
find all cell-taskname in that (100)
select all cell-text in those (10000)
```

in the 3rd (my first) scenario, you work with 2.01m elements

in the 1st (my second) scenario, you work with only 10101 elements. So that is why it's that much faster :-)

of course, these aren't exact performance numbers, but it does explain the concept behind selector optimizations...