# CSS: Is it important to specify the exact path for a particular element for speed/accuracy?

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors

When defining CSS for a particular element does **specifying exact path** make any difference when we are talking about **speed/accuracy/processing** of a web page?

for e.g. if I have text inputs **ONLY** in 3rd column of my table, which is better for speed, accuracy, processing and other parameters?

**OPTION 1:**

```
table input[type="text"]
{
    background:yellow;
}
```

**OPTION 2:**

```
table td:nth-child(3) input[type="text"]
{
    background:yellow;
}
```

Comment: [This may be useful for you](http://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/)

Comment: @Pete: Thanks for the link. Very descriptive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, adding more compound selectors just gives the browser more elements to check and thus more work to do.

If the inputs will only ever appear in a specific place and you can guarantee that they will never appear anywhere else in a given page, then however precise you make your selector beyond `input[type="text"]` is irrelevant because it will always target the same set of elements anyway. Any extra checks you add then become redundant.

But the real question is whether performance even matters here. Unless you have tens of thousands of such elements, chances are the answer is no. Be as specific as you feel comfortable with. If you need the contextual selectors to make sure you don't accidentally target the wrong elements, there is no harm in putting them in.

Comment: In case of 2nd option, isn't it most likely that the browser doesn't need to search for text inputs in columns other than 3rd column?

Comment: @nikunj: It depends. Most implementations do what is called [right-to-left evaluation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797014/why-do-browsers-match-css-selectors-from-right-to-left), which means they check every `input[type="text"]` first before determining whether they appear in a `td:nth-child(3)`, rather than limiting their scope first.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! Was anxious about this for a long time! :)

Comment: You don't have to worry. There are some general good practices out there that are worth following, but performance is not something that you have to be concerned with all the time. Build it, then see if it really needs optimizing.