# nth-of-type selector combined with sibling selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm confused on how the `nth-of-type` selector works in conjunction with the sibling selector. In the example below, I'd expect squares 3, 4, and 5 to be red, but they aren't. How does the `.bar ~ div:nth-of-type(-n+3)` selector below select elements?

If I wanted to get the first three elements after `.bar` what would be the proper selector to do that?

```css
.foo {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
.bar {
  background: green;
}
.bar ~ div {
  background-color: orange;
}
.bar ~ div:nth-of-type(-n+3) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="foo">0</div>
  <div class="foo">1</div>
  <div class="foo bar">2</div>
  <div class="foo">3</div>
  <div class="foo">4</div>
  <div class="foo">5</div>
  <div class="foo">6</div>
  <div class="foo">7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.bar ~ div:nth-of-type(-n+3)` means:

1. `:nth-of-type(-n+3)`: select every element which is among the first three of its type inside its parent
2. `div`: restrict to `div` elements only
3. `.bar ~`: restrict to elements which have a previous sibling (not necessarily immediately) with the class `bar`.

Since any of the following siblings of `.bar` isn't among the three first `div` elements, the selector doesn't match anything.

If you want to get the three `.foo` elements immediately after `.bar`, you can use:

```
.bar + .foo, .bar + .foo + .foo, .bar + .foo + .foo + .foo
```

```css
.foo {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
.bar {
  background: green;
}
.bar ~ div {
  background-color: orange;
}
.bar + .foo, .bar + .foo + .foo, .bar + .foo + .foo + .foo {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="foo">0</div>
  <div class="foo">1</div>
  <div class="foo bar">2</div>
  <div class="foo">3</div>
  <div class="foo">4</div>
  <div class="foo">5</div>
  <div class="foo">6</div>
  <div class="foo">7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't `-n` select starting from the end? I can't seem to find anything that directly explains what `-n` does.

Comment: @TylerH Nope, check out the last example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#Examples

Comment: @Oriol Thanks. I was thinking "left to right" instead of "right to left". Of course, "right to left" is how it actually works... related reading for anyone interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797014/why-do-browsers-match-css-selectors-from-right-to-left?lq=1

Comment: So how do you go about getting the first 3 siblings after the div.bar element?  @JKillian

Comment: @JKillian Ah, I see. I was also forgetting that selectors are interpreted RTL. `-n` makes it bounce back the way it came, *per se*.

Comment: @SohrabHejazi Technically, that wasn't in my original question, but I do also want to know that as well. I believe you could do something hacky like `.bar + div, .bar + div + div, .bar + div + div + div` but that's kind of messy. _Edit_: Ninja'd by Oriol

Comment: @JKillian Yes that is kind of messy.  That's the only way I have found as well.  Your question led me to try to figure that out.  I'm trying to see if there is a cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: In [Selectors L4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#nth-child-pseudo) I think it will be possible to do something like `:nth-child(3-n of .bar~.foo)`. But no browser supports it yet.

Comment: @JKillian: The RTL thing is completely irrelevant. See my comment on the accepted answer.

Comment: @TylerH: That would make a good question for SO, I think. I haven't found a single article explaining how `-n` works either. I had to figure it out entirely on my own.

Comment: @BoltClock Good correction, thanks. I suppose I was thinking about it like: "1. Select all `.bar` elements. 2. Select siblings following these `.bar` elements. 3. Narrow these siblings down to `div` elements only 4. Narrow these down to the first three `div` elements for each `.bar` element." Of course, even if browsers went LTR over combinators, this still isn't what would happen.