# Which CSS selector is faster in performance? Class in Class vs tagName in Class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Note: this question does not have a similar match on SO.

I am aware that the CSS selectors are read right to left. I am also aware that CSS class selectors should not be additionally qualified with a tagname.

But which among these will be **faster** (not talking about specificity):

```
.group   div { ...
.group .item { ...
```

for this HTML:

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Since it is from right to left, doesn't it mean that in the first case, Browser will search for only `div`s (and thus faster) compared to second case, where Browser will search for every element that has a class of `item` (before even comparing the parent with the `.group` class)?

Comment: Does "for this HTML" mean there is no other HTML in the page?

Comment: Faster to do what?  The only way to know for sure is to do a benchmark.  It probably depends on which browser is used.  I would guess that in most cases you wouldn't be able to measure a difference.

Comment: @Oriol, how does it matter if the page had other HTML?

Comment: @KingJulian:  By affecting the speed of whatever you're measuring.

Comment: @KingJulian, the number of elements (especially the number of `div`s, elements with class `item`, and elements with class `group`) would definitely make a difference in terms of performance.

Comment: @recursive, faster in selecting and painting. 
Also, how would it matter? Since even if the page had more HTML, this particular group will always be treated in it's own left to right. So there will be a linear relation to performance!

Comment: I don't understand your argument.  There's a linear relationship between performance and what?  There can't be a linear relationship for a single variable.  

The rest of the contents of the page could matter.  If there are other `.group`s or `.item`s or `div`s, some of those may be considered by the selector.  That consideration costs time.  That affects the speed of completion.  The exact cost depends on the exact configuration.

Comment: @KingJulian It seems you are missing that CSS selectors in a stylesheet can potentially select any element in the document, they are not restricted to some fragment. What makes sense is asking how some selectors perform with a huge HTML. But it doesn't make any sense to ask for just 2 HTML elements because with 2 elements any selector, whatever its complexity, even including things like `:has` that browsers don't implement because are too slow, will be incredibly fast.

Comment: @Oriol, that's right. I took for granted that there will be a lot of HTML and I would not need to explain the same. But since you mentioned regarding being fast, there will still be some difference between the 2 **irrespective of if the page had other HTML**. The question is about that difference, hence.

Comment: >"...there will still be some difference between the 2 **irrespective of if the page had other HTML**" It's negligible unless we are back in the 90s.

Comment: @zer00ne, it might be. But that gives an idea which will be faster when there's a lot of HTML, my original Question.

Comment: All this time you're wasting discussing theoretical performance, that you could have spent actually profiling them to see if there was any meaningful difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would expect `.group .item` to be (neglibibly) faster.

That's because, most probably, the number of `div` elements will be greater than the number of elements with class `item`.

So if you use `.group div`, every `div` will match the `div` part, and the browser will have to ensure there is a `.group` ancestor. If you use `.group .item`, every `.item` will match the `.item` part, and the browser will have to ensure there is a `.group` ancestor.

For better performance, you want to avoid false positives, and if a selector is not going to match an element, you want to reject it as soon as possible. So `.group .item` should be faster if there are less `.item` than `div`.

Anyways, use child selectors instead of descendant ones if you can. Seems reasonable for the formers to be faster.

Comment: that's what I am confused at. 
In the second case too, how does the browser find the `.item`? It will actually check for **every** element right, which should be slower than checking for `div` only.

How does browser identify these elements? Does it identify them by tag first, and then check for prop values like class? In that case, it should be **faster to select** in the first case, right?

Comment: There's no reason that it *must* check every element.  It could have an internal index by class name.  Browsers are free to implement their own selectors however they want.

Comment: Why would checking every element for `.item` be any slower than checking if every element is a `div`?

Comment: @dlsso It seems you think browsers iterate selectors, and for each selector they select all elements which match that selector. Not usually. Browsers iterate elements, and for each element they check what selectors apply to that element.

Comment: @recursive, "It could have an internal index by class name" - that's what I want to know from the question, if it was true. I am expecting answers that explain how this index is maintained and so as to decide on speed. 
Also, fyi, browsers do index elements based on `id` attribute. I don't know if it was true for classNames

Comment: @dlsso, that's what I want to know from this question. Do browsers index elements based on tagNames? I know that they do based on `id`. If the browser indexed elements based on tagNames, then tagName selection should be faster in my question (irrespective of specificity which will be more in className)

Comment: @KingJulian, recursive You also seem to think that browsers iterate selectors instead of elements. Most browsers iterate elements. All elements will be iterated, whatever indices they use. It's the other way round, browsers use indices that track which selectors could potentially select the current element.

Comment: I was actually envisioning iterating by element. Are you saying that because it's going by element it already knows if it's a `div` and thus that check is "free?"

Comment: @dlsso: That does indeed appear to be the case [at least in Gecko](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797014/why-do-browsers-match-css-selectors-from-right-to-left#comment16359305_5813672). However, if I'm reading it right, the same applies to classes and ids, and not just tagnames.