# C# Selenium Web Driver and CSS : Start point

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver

I have the next tags structure:

```
<body>
   <parent>
       <nested/>
   </parent>
</body>
```

I do the following thing:

```
IWebDriver _driver;

var parent = _driver.FindElement(By.Css("parent"));
var nested = parent.FindElement(By.Css("parent nested"));
```

Notice, I need to find nested element only this way: **at first I find parent tag, then I use parent as a start point to find nested one**.
But when I use logically wrong locator("parent nested", because together "parent parent nested" is wrong locator), parent.FindElement **returns(!)** me correct IWebElement, just like if I searched from the top of DOM model.

The interesting thing is that when I do

```
var nested = parent.FindElement(By.Css("parent"));
```

it throws element not found exception.

I think I understand something wrong or just don't know something. How does it work? How I can avoid problem of "parent parent nested" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> cssSelectors will be evaluated from right to left.

that means first children will be evaluated and then check whether their parent exists.

In your case,

```
var nested = parent.FindElement(By.Css("parent nested"));
```

first, check whether `nested` element is present as a child in the DOM (here, nested element). if present, then check whether `parent` is its parent.

and

```
var nested = parent.FindElement(By.Css("parent"));
```

here, `parent` will be checked whether it is a child of the given element (calling on parent). but it is not. so, gives `NoSuchElementException`

Reference:

1. [Why do browsers match CSS selectors from right to left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797014/why-do-browsers-match-css-selectors-from-right-to-left)

Comment: Thanks both you and @NarendraRajput

Answer (score 3):

I think here you are using wrong way thats why you are getting error

```
var nested = parent.FindElement(By.Css("parent"));
```

Here you are doing -

> "first  find parent tag, then I use parent as a start point to find
>   parent tag itself"

which is wrong. There can be different ways to get this -

1. make parent tag as start point and find child tag -

`var child= driver.FindElement(By.Css("parent")).FindElement(By.Css("nested"));`

2. Directly find child tag  -

`var child= driver.FindElement(By.Css("parent nested"));`

Comment: You are right, but if you do var child= driver.FindElement(By.Css("parent")).FindElement(By.Css("parent nested"));  (take a look at the second locator) you ll get a correct element anyway. I just wanna understand why.

Comment: because `By.Css("par‌​ent nested")` find the sub-child as "nested" of parent tag so no matter either you can find that sub-child either `By.Css("parent nested")` or can move through make parent as start point and then move to child like `var child= driver.FindElement(By.Css("parent")).FindElement(By.Css("par‌​ent nested"));` indirectly it is also finding that sub-child element.

Comment: `Css("parent nested")` is alternative of  ``xpath("//parent//nested")`` as you are going to locate nested element in this way too