# queryselectorAll with descendant not selecting correctly

Tags: javascript, dom, selectors-api

I have the following DOM structure:

```js
    var parent = document.querySelector(".test");
    var navChild = parent.querySelectorAll("ul > li > a");
    for (i = 0; i < navChild.length; i++) {
            navChild[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
    console.log(navChild.lenght);
    console.log(navChild);
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
    <ul>
      <li class="test">
        <a>ssss</a> <!--this will also be affected -->
        <ul>
          <li><a>fsfsf</a></li>
          <li><a>sff</a></li>
          <li><a>ggg</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

I want to select the 3 `a` tags using vanilla javascript and starting from the `li` with the class test. I put this in a `parent` variable and then use querySelectorAll to try to get only the `a` tags that are inside the next list. However, the nodelist that is returned also includes the very first `a` tag even though it's not a descendant. This is my code:

```
var navChild = parent.querySelectorAll("ul > li > a");
```

What's really weird is that if I query for just the `li` descendants I get only the 3. So I don't understand why when I query for the child descendant of that `li` I also get that first `a` tag that is two levels up on the DOM.

I know I could do this using jQuery but I don't want to use it.

**EDITED to show how I'm setting the parent variable**

I'm trying to add those `a` tags to the `childs` variable after I've hit the enter keyboard button while on the first `a` tag that I don't want to include in the childs node list.

```
var alinks = document.querySelectorAll('.test > a');
[].forEach.call(alinks, function(link){
    link.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(e.keyCode === 13) {
            var linkParent = e.target.parentElement;
            var childs = menuParent.querySelectorAll('ul > li > a');
        }        
    })
});
```

When I log `linkParent` it is correctly being set as the `li` with class `test`. I don't understand why then if I run the query from there it still includes the very first `a` tag. As I previously stated, if I query just `ul > li` it gives me the correct `li` tags.

Comment: Show how you're setting `parent`.

Comment: Related: [Why does querySelector('div span') match even though querySelector('div') does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64522987/4642212).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the first `<a>` tag you're trying to ignore still falls into the selector rule `ul > li > a`. So, even though you start the query with the `<li class="test">` as the root (which does work by the way, I don't know why the other answers say that the document is still the root), the first child element it finds is the `<a>` tag and, indeed, it is the child of an `<li>` which is the child of a `<ul>`. The fact that this winds up going "above" your specified root is ignored.

**Edit:**
If you want the selector rule to be scoped to the root as well, you can use this instead:

```
parent.querySelectorAll(":scope ul > li > a");
```

And to further clarify, [browser CSS engines evaluate CSS rules right-to-left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797014/why-do-browsers-match-css-selectors-from-right-to-left). In your mind, you want the browser to start at the root (the parent `<li class="test">`) and then find a `<ul>` tag and then find a `<li>` tag and then find an `<a>` tag.

However, the browser starts with the root, but then looks for all of the `<a>` tags below the root. Then it checks if the `<a>` tag is within an `<li>` and then if the `<li>` is within a `<ul>`. So the `<li class="parent">` tag really is the root, but it does not follow the left-to-right hierarchy of your selector rule after that, it goes right-to-left.

Comment: So you're saying that when running that type of descendant query it always ignores the root and just finds items that fit into the selector rule??

Comment: @chavab_1 No, that's not what I'm saying. It will only find items that fit into the selector rule that are below the root -- that first `<a>` tag is below the root. But, the part that it "ignores" is that the `<a>` tag's parent elements which are what make it fit into the rule can be above the root.

Comment: @chavab_1 If that's not the behavior you want, see my edit about adding in `:scope`

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know that; I was expecting the same behavior as when the selector rule is used in CSS. I found the exact answer, just as you have explained, in this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll
Everything is working now. Once again, Thanx!!

Comment: I found out that the `:scope` pseudo-class is not supported in IE (big surprise) nor Opera. Do you have an alternate way to tackle this task?? I could just disregard the first node in the nodelist and it would fix that issue, but then I also have to make sure I only select the nodes that are direct descendants since each of the child `a`s could also have a `ul` , `li` and `a`s of its own. The only thing I can think of is to use the `children` method until I get to the nodes that I need. But I just think there has to be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your first `<a>` also matches `ul > li > a`, and since said `a` is still a descendant of the element qSA was called upon, it gets included in the NodeList.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll#Javascript

Element.querySelector and Element.querySelectorAll are somewhat quirky in that respect: although the only matching elements must be children of the Element you called it on, the selector string *still starts at the document level* - it doesn't verify the selector by isolating the element and its descendants first.

```js
const child = document.querySelector('#child');
const span = child.querySelector('#parent span');
console.log(span.textContent);
```

```html
<div id="parent">
<div id="child">
<span>text</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this doesn't really answer the question.  the child selector (`>`) is being used, so it should only be returning `a` elements that are children of `li` elements that in turn are children of `ul` elements.  This is acting more like he used `ul > li, li > a`

Comment: The `a` he wasn't expecting to be selected *is* an `a` that matches `ul > li > a`.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "quirky". It accurately selects elements that meet the description of the selector. They can use `:scope` to constrain the selection. `parent.querySelectorAll(":scope ul > li > a");`

Answer (score 0):

Use this to define your `var navChild = document.querySelectorAll("test > ul > li > a");`. I had to use a running example to solve the issue. This will get the 3 vanilla `<a>` you want

The [querySelectorAll()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp) method returns all elements in the document that matches a specified CSS selector(s), as a static NodeList object.

I presume this is true even when you set a parent within the document.

```js
var navChild = document.querySelectorAll(".test > ul > li > a");
for (i = 0; i < navChild.length; i++) {
        navChild[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
//console.log(navChild.lenght);
//console.log(navChild);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="test">
    <a>qqqq</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a>aaa</a></li>
      <li><a>bbb</a></li>
      <li><a>ccc</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's not correct - qSA called on an element only selects children of that element.

Comment: @CertainPerformance If you edit my running example and use the following:
`var parent = document.querySelector(".test");
    var navChild = parent.querySelectorAll("ul > li > a");`
All 4 bullets are affected.

Comment: Yes, but the first `<a>` in your code is still a child of the parent `.test` - that doesn't mean that element.qSA always selects every element in the document, it just means that your example is faulty. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/qt83o3ph/

Comment: Could you elaborate on the example being faulty? I see that you removed `<a>` from the `ul > li > a` and placed it outside. I think it would of been more effective to display another list with the same structure. I see what you mean in that scenario but not the scenario that was trying to be resolved. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/qt83o3ph/6/

Comment: You implied that the first <a> being selected was an example of `element.qSA` selecting all matching elements in the document, but the `<a>qqqq</a>` *is still a child of* `#test`, so it would be selected regardless of qSA selecting all matching elements or only selecting matching elements which are children of the element qSA is being called on. (another problem is that `("test > ul > li > a")` won't work unless there happens to be a nonstandard tag `<test>` in the document)

Comment: @CertainPerformance thank you. I am still trying to resolve your of information for I am interested :) The `class='test'` was part of the original problem, and hence that's why that is in the solution. With the first embedded `<a>` as a child of the qS for the parent `test`, it is still being selected. The qSA of `li > a` is only present in this case, how is the `ul` tag being ignored or added to the parent of test? Added another `<li>` tag with an embedded `<span><a>` tags. The behaviour is as expected because it does not meet the qSA standard. Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/qt83o3ph/11/

Comment: In your fiddle, the `<a>test</a>` does not match `ul > li > a` because the `a` in question is not a direct descendant of a `li` - it's a descendant of a *span*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167841/discussion-between-mcv-and-certainperformance).