# Multiple descendant selectors, bug or misunderstanding?

Tags: javascript, css, queryselector

Shouldn't the following two approaches to selecting a node produce the same result?

```
let tmp = fruits.querySelector("ul:first-of-type li:first-of-type");
tmp = tmp.querySelector("span")
```

vs.

```
let tmp = fruits.querySelector("ul:first-of-type li:first-of-type span");
```

(See it in action [here](https://codepen.io/mnlipp/pen/gOgvbMw?editors=1111))

I've tested this in both firefox and chrome. Different results in both cases. Can anybody please explain why?

Example in stack snippet:

```js
let fruits = document.querySelector("[data-segment='fruits']");
console.log(fruits);
let tmp = fruits.querySelector("ul:first-of-type li:first-of-type")
tmp = tmp.querySelector("span")
console.log("Works:")
console.log(tmp)
console.log("Does not work:")
console.log(fruits.querySelector("ul:first-of-type li:first-of-type span"))
```

```html
<main id="app" data-v-app="">
  <section>
    <h2>Tree</h2>
    <ul role="tree">
      <li role="treeitem" data-segment="fruits" aria-level="1" aria-setsize="3" aria-posinset="1" aria-expanded="true"><span tabindex="0">Fruits</span>
        <ul role="group">
          <li role="none" data-segment="oranges" aria-level="2" aria-setsize="5" aria-posinset="1"><span tabindex="-1">Oranges</span>
            <!--v-if-->
          </li>
          <li role="none" data-segment="pineapple" aria-level="2" aria-setsize="5" aria-posinset="2"><span tabindex="-1">Pineapple</span>
            <!--v-if-->
          </li>
          <li role="treeitem" data-segment="apples" aria-level="2" aria-setsize="5" aria-posinset="3" aria-expanded="false"><span tabindex="-1">Apples</span>
            <ul role="group">
              <li role="none" data-segment="macintosh" aria-level="3" aria-setsize="3" aria-posinset="1"><span tabindex="-1">Macintosh</span>
                <!--v-if-->
              </li>
              <li role="none" data-segment="granny_smith" aria-level="3" aria-setsize="3" aria-posinset="2"><span tabindex="-1">Granny Smith</span>
                <!--v-if-->
              </li>
              <li role="none" data-segment="fuji" aria-level="3" aria-setsize="3" aria-posinset="3"><span tabindex="-1">Fuji</span>
                <!--v-if-->
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li role="none" data-segment="bananas" aria-level="2" aria-setsize="5" aria-posinset="4"><span tabindex="-1">Bananas</span>
            <!--v-if-->
          </li>
          <li role="none" data-segment="pears" aria-level="2" aria-setsize="5" aria-posinset="5"><span tabindex="-1">Pears</span>
            <!--v-if-->
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li role="none" data-segment="vegetables" aria-level="1" aria-setsize="3" aria-posinset="2"><span tabindex="-1">Vegetables</span>
        <!--v-if-->
      </li>
      <li role="none" data-segment="grains" aria-level="1" aria-setsize="3" aria-posinset="3"><span tabindex="-1">Grains</span>
        <!--v-if-->
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: I ran it and same result in 3 different browsers.

Comment: [The last example pretty much explains why it works that way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)

Comment: the most upsetting thing for me is that `fruits.querySelector("ul:first-of-type li:first-of-type")` selects the *Oranges* `<li>` while `fruits.querySelector("ul:first-of-type li:first-of-type span")` selects the *Fruits* `<span>`

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+queryselector+matches+element+outside+of+parent) of [Why does querySelector('div span') match even though querySelector('div') does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64522987/4642212) and [queryselectorAll with descendant not selecting correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49545252/4642212).

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector#return_value) explains it:

> ```js
> element = baseElement.querySelector(selectors);
> ```
>
> ### Return value
>
> The first descendant element of `baseElement` which matches the specified group of `selectors`. **The entire hierarchy of elements is considered when matching, including those outside the set of elements including `baseElement` and its descendants**; in other words, `selectors` is first applied to the whole document, not the `baseElement`, to generate an initial list of potential elements. The resulting elements are then examined to see **if they are descendants of `baseElement`**. The first match of those remaining elements is returned by the `querySelector` method.

(Emphasis mine.)

Let’s consider a simplified example:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("a").querySelector("ul li span"));
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="a"><span>A</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>B</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here, `baseElement` is `document.getElementById("a")`; `selectors` is `"ul li span"`.

`document.querySelector("ul li span")` indeed includes both `<span>`s, and both of them are inside `baseElement`. `<span>A</span>` happens to be the first one that is in this set.

There’s a rather new pseudo-class called [`:scope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope) that may help here:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("a").querySelector(":scope ul li span"));
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="a"><span>A</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>B</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It just occurred to me that you can't have a relative selector that starts with a descendant combinator - the only instance of the :scope pseudo being mandatory in a scoped selector.

Comment: Ah, @BoltClock, I remember when you'd have written a beautiful canonical answer to this question yourself. For what it's worth: I miss those days (and please do feel free to delete this horribly tangential comment once you've read it)

Comment: @David: I don't  It must've been forever. You happen to have a link? (Unless it's [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28708741/how-do-i-select-an-element-based-on-the-state-of-another-element-in-the-page-wit/28793064#28793064).)

Comment: @BoltClock, it wasn't so much that I remembered a specific answer you wrote it's just that I recalled reading several of your answers in which you went to the spec and wrote something along the lines of an essay - in an engaging manner - to fully and exhaustively answer the question posed.

Comment: @David: Oh, right, "you'd have written", not "you'd written". Yeah, I would have, though it'd probably be roughly the same as what Sebastian's got here, with the exception that I'd quote the DOM spec and not MDN (but MDN is just fine here).

Answer (score 1):

`el.querySelector(selector)` can return surprising results if you're not aware of how it works in the background.

```
 el.querySelector(selector)
```

What really is going on is like this:

```
 (el, selector) => [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)].filter(node => el !== node && el.contains(node))[0]
```

See this example:

```js
const el = document.getElementById('outer');
const selector = 'span > span';
console.log(el.querySelector(selector).id); // logs "inner", not "innermost"
// same as if you did
console.log([...document.querySelectorAll(selector)].filter(node => el !== node && el.contains(node))[0].id);
```

```html
<span id="outermost">
  <span id="outer">
    <span id="inner">
      <span id="innermost"></span>
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

So `el.querySelector(selector)` returns the first match from if you did `document.querySelectorAll(selector)` that satisfies the condition that the node found must be a descendant of `el`.

Even more surprising, `el.querySelector` even finds a match if you pass a `selector` that you'd think has no matches because parts of the `selector` aren't even inside the `el`:

```js
const el = document.getElementById('outer');
const selector = '#outermost > span > span';
console.log(el.querySelector(selector).id); // logs "inner"!
// same as if you did
console.log([...document.querySelectorAll(selector)].filter(node => el !== node && el.contains(node))[0].id);
```

```html
<span id="outermost">
  <span id="outer">
    <span id="inner">
      <span id="innermost"></span>
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```