# Why CSS attribute selector followed by element tag is slower?

Tags: css, vue.js, webkit

According to Vue docs [here](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#child-component-root-elements):

> Due to the way browsers render various CSS selectors, `p { color: red }`
>   will be many times slower when scoped (i.e. when combined with an
>   attribute selector). If you use classes or ids instead, such as in
>   `.example { color: red }`, then you virtually eliminate that performance
>   hit

So if you put the following in the Vue's style section:

```
<style scoped>
  .parent .child { 
    background-color: red;
  }

  .parent p {
    background-color: red;
  }

</style>
```

The VueJs will transform it into this:

```
<style>
  .parent[data-v-12345] .child {
    background-color: red;
  }

  .parent[data-v-12345] p { 
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

The document says, the second selector is many times slower than the first one.

**Can someone explain why the second selector is slower?**

Comment: well ( and this is just a guess ) . If you are more specific ( using a class ) the element can be found faster. I presume in your example the number of `.class` and `p` elements are equal.

Comment: Well this might be correct in general but Vue document clearly says you get a performance penalty when `p` is following `[some-attribute]`. That's what I'm curious about.

Comment: The reason is because browsers match CSS from right to left  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797014/why-do-browsers-match-css-selectors-from-right-to-left.  It's nothing specific to the `p` tag.  It's that the specificity gains of using an ID/class are reduced/lost when a generic tag selector follows it.

Comment: So @Dan based on what you're saying, there's also nothing specific about the attribute selectors as well. Any selector followed by an element tag, `.parent p` should behave equally bad regardless of the parent selector.

Comment: Yeah, I think the idea is that the renderer has to traverse up the DOM to check each parent, grandparent, etc.  So it should actually be even slower than a single element selector under certain (all?) circumstances.  For example, multiple deeply nested matches.