# How to cancel the inheritance of the "li:before {content: 'text'}" without reassigning it for each <li> element?

Tags: html, css, css-content

everyone!

**The general goal is that all li elements for which a property is not explicitly declared use the standard value.**

I don't understand why the content property can't be reset:

```css
ul {
 position: relative;
 list-style: none;
 margin-left: 0;
 padding-left: 1.2em;
}

li:before {
 content: unset;
}

ul > li:before {
 content: "A";
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
}

ul > ul > li:before {
 content: "B";
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>Level 1 Item 1</li>
 <ul>
  <li>Level 2 Item 1</li>
  <ul>
   <li>Level 3 Item 1</li>
   <li>Level 3 Item 2</li>
   <li>Level 3 Item 3</li>
  </ul>
 </ul>
</ul>
```

Result:

[image: Actual result: level 3 content is not unset and still shown]

But shouldn't the result be like this:

[image: Expected result: level 3 content is unset and hidden]

How can I fix this so that the result is the same as in the last picture?

Comment: @BoltClock thanks for support to insert image. I think maybe I should change the title of the question: How to cancel the inheritance of the "content property" without reassigning it for each <li> element?

Comment: Good call, you may make further edits to your own question. I'm currently writing an answer.

Comment: You should use the DOM inspector to see how the styles are applied to an element.

Comment: **Your HTML is invalid to begin with. It needs to be fixed before anything else can be addressed.** `ul` can only have `li`, `script` and `template` children. That being said, `ul > ul` is not supposed to **ever** match an element, and if it does, that is most certainly a violation of the spec and could (and honestly **should**) stop working at any point in time.

Comment: @connexo That is, if I want to create an attachment, I need to declare the new level as "ul > li > ul"?

Comment: If you need to nest `ul`s, the nested `ul`s need to reside in `li`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a class to your `ul` tags. I made a slight change in your second `li` selector by removing `ul > li > li:before` to `ul.myClass > li:before`. Run the code snippet and you will see your desired output

```css
ul {
 position: relative;
 list-style: none;
 margin-left: 0;
 padding-left: 1.2em;
}

li:before {
 content: unset;
}

ul.myParentClass > li:before {
 content: "A";
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
}

ul.myClass > li:before {
 content: "B";
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="myParentClass">
 <li>Level 1 Item 1</li>
 <ul class="myClass">
  <li>Level 2 Item 1</li>
  <ul>
   <li>Level 3 Item 1</li>
   <li>Level 3 Item 2</li>
   <li>Level 3 Item 3</li>
  </ul>
 </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: My goal is to do without class selectors (

Comment: It's just that I plan to use a huge number of sub-lists.

Comment: Do you have another `ul` inside `level 3`  `li` element?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I just need a general plan solution, how to undo inheritance without reassigning the property for each sublevel

Comment: Okay if that's a possibility then you need to use JS. The solution I can think of is using a `function` which will check if the list you're trying to render has `child` list element or not. Based upon that you should add a class to the `ul` which doesn't have any child element. Also instead of setting the content, you can use `list-style-type:upper-alpha;`

Comment: I found my mistake and solutions. I'll add an explanation to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You're unsetting it with a simple `li:before` selector. That's going to be overridden by your other rules with `ul >`s, in particular the most specific `ul > ul > li:before` because it includes your level 3 items (children of the level 2 and level 1 `ul` elements). You'll need another one of these selectors, nested 3 levels, to unset it for those particular items:

```css
ul {
 position: relative;
 list-style: none;
 margin-left: 0;
 padding-left: 1.2em;
}

ul > li:before {
 content: "A";
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
}

ul > ul > li:before {
 content: "B";
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
}

ul > ul > ul > li:before {
 content: unset;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>Level 1 Item 1</li>
 <ul>
  <li>Level 2 Item 1</li>
  <ul>
   <li>Level 3 Item 1</li>
   <li>Level 3 Item 2</li>
   <li>Level 3 Item 3</li>
  </ul>
 </ul>
</ul>
```

On a side note, I'd recommend either

- (recommended) changing `:before` to `::before` since you're writing CSS3 that's not going to work in CSS2-only browsers anyway, or
- using `content: none` instead of `content: unset`, which will allow your code to be supported in CSS2-only browsers, if you care about that

Comment: I may have specified the target incorrectly. The task is to make an unset for those li elements that do not have a property specified.

Comment: Please tell me how I can clarify my question. Should I add more code?

Comment: @isNaN: The content property isn't inherited. It's just that your selectors are matching your nested li elements (which isn't a mistake on your part, just a limitation of selectors). I suppose you could clarify what you mean by "li elements that do not have a property specified" - what property exactly?

Comment: For "Level 3 Item 1", I don't specify the content property, but it still inherits from "Level 2 Item 1"

Comment: From the selector's point of view, is this the right thing to do? ul > ul > li:before {content: "B";}, but "Level 3 Item 1" is ul > ul > ul > li:before

Comment: @isNaN: I've added an explanation to my answer. Not sure it's my best explanation but let me know if it helps.

Comment: Tell me, do I understand correctly that inheritance cannot be undone, if I do not use reassignments for each sublevel?

Comment: @isNaN: As I said earlier, there is no inheritance in the first place. You can't sever an inheritance chain that isn't there.

Comment: My brain is about to explode. Well, I applied the CSS rule: "ul > ul > li::before {
 content: 'B';
}" why is this added to "ul > ul > ul > li::before" ?

Comment: @isNaN: Because "ul > **ul > ul > li::before**"

Comment: I found my mistake and solutions. I'll add an explanation to the question.

Comment: BoltClock, YES, this is my mistake, I realized it.

Comment: My solution: "*:not(ul) > ul > ul > li::before"

Comment: <Because "ul > ul > ul > li::before">    Thank you. I guessed that, too. I wish you had mentioned this point earlier. Updated: Well, thank you.

Comment: @isNaN: That's a good approach! You can post it as your own answer. As you're new to the site I'd also like to inform you that we try to avoid extended discussions in comments, so avoid posting multiple comments in a row if you can help it. You can edit your own comments for 5 minutes at a time.

Comment: The HTML is invalid to begin with. It needs to be fixed before anything else can be addressed. `ul` can only have `li`, `script` and `template` children. That being said, `ul > ul` is not supposed to **ever** match an element, and if it does, that is most certainly a violation of the spec and could (and honestly **should**) stop working at any point in time.

Comment: Also, your 2 recommendations at the end of your post contradict. Edit: I see you wrote "*either*" in the introduction to those two points. Please consider fattening that.

Comment: @connexo: Good point on the HTML being invalid, that slipped my mind, but the HTML spec doesn't say that ul > ul must match nothing just because a ul is not allowed to be a child of another ul. While it's questionable to rely on ul > ul matching, it's not a violation of any spec if it does.

Comment: The spec violation is on the HTML side, `ul` as child of `ul`. On top of that, relying on the browser not to autocorrect that (like it'd do if you had `<table><tr><td>` which the browser would automatically turn into `<table><tbody><tr><td>`) on the CSS side is more than just questionable.

Comment: @connexo: Fair enough, you were saying earlier that ul > ul matching was a spec violation and that's what I was disagreeing with. The debate of selectors matching in invalid documents is one that's been had [elsewhere on SO at length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797014/why-do-browsers-match-css-selectors-from-right-to-left), and the CSSWG has insisted that they're not responsible for authors writing invalid markup, so I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

*This question is generated by my inheritance error. I shouldn't have blamed CSS for my problem. CSS did everything right...*

Solution (*use the check for the absence of the previous level* — **:not(ul)**):

```
*:not(ul) > ul > ul > li::before {
 content: "B";
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
}
```