# Sibling selectors and first-of-type don't work when I try to select the first ul element after a prior one

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

For context: I'm looking at this [webpage](https://rpgbot.net/dnd5/characters/classes/warlock/invocations.html), and I'm trying to figure out what to put in the dev console to sort each of the unordered lists by the star rating. Here is a snippet of the actual html I want to re-order:

```html
<h3 id="invocations-level-1">Level 1</h3>
<p>some intro</p>
<ul>
  <!-- <li><a href="" class="rating-"></a><sup><a href="/dnd5/abbreviations/"></a></sup>: </li> -->
  <li><a href="https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/classes#AgonizingBlast" class="rating-blue">Agonizing Blast</a><sup><a href="/dnd5/abbreviations/">PHB</a></sup>: Nearly every Warlock takes this. The damage is simply too good to pass up. The damage grows
    multiplicatively as you get additional rays, so the total additional damage will range from +3 at low levels to a maximum +20 at 17th level.</li>
  <li><a href="https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/classes#ArmorofShadows" class="rating-orange">Armor of Shadows</a><sup><a href="/dnd5/abbreviations/">PHB</a></sup>: You already get light armor, and Mage Armor is only +1 AC over studded leather. You don't
    get enough invocations to justify wasting one on this. Hexblades might consider this to close the AC gap between light/medium and heavy armor, but I'm not convinced that this is better than multiclassing to get heavy armor proficiency.</li>
  <li><a href="https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/classes#BeastSpeech" class="rating-red">Beast Speech</a><sup><a href="/dnd5/abbreviations/">PHB</a></sup>: Very situational.</li>
</ul>
<h3 id="invocations-level-3">Level 3 (Requires Pact Boon)</h3>
<p>some intro</p>
<span id="some-ad"></span>
<span class="some-other-ad">...</span>
<ul><li>...</li></ul>
```

Each of the lists, for each level (1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 15), is currently sorted alphabetically by invocation name (e.g. Agonizing Blast, Armor of Shadows ), but I was hoping to re-order it based on the classes (of the form `rating-{blue,green,orange,red}`.

My MVCE code that only works on the first lot of ul elements:

```js
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 15].forEach((level, index) => $$('div#main-content > ul')[index].innerHTML = [].map.call(['blue', 'green', 'orange', 'red'].flatMap(colour => $$('#invocations-level-'+level+' + p + ul li a.rating-' + colour)), function(el) {
    return el.parentElement.outerHTML;
}));
```

(this is using the native `document.querySelectorAll`, no jQuery involved atm)

This only works for the first ul element, because this part `$$('#invocations-level-1 + p + ul li a.rating-blue')` is too specific in terms of direct sibling selection. In the second section, after `<h3 id="invocations-level-3">Level 3 (Requires Pact Boon)</h3>` there is a paragraph, but then also some spans. In later sections (not listed above), there're no spans or paragraph elements.

I've tried a few iterations of sibling selector combinations like `$$('#invocations-level-3 ~ ul:first-of-type')` (this doesn't work at `-level-3`, despite working at `-level-1`), and also `$$('#invocations-level-3 ~ ul:not(ul~ul)')` again that works at `-level-1`, but none subsequently.

I can use index access like so `$$('#invocations-level-3 ~ ul')[0]` but then I can't continue drilling down into the `' ... li a.rating-'+colour'` part of the selector.

Can I do this without having to involve jQuery, and just one selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Using `nth-of-type` that scales with each ul works

```js
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 15].forEach((level, index) => $$('div#main-content > ul')[index].innerHTML = [].map.call(['blue', 'green', 'orange', 'red'].flatMap(colour => $$('#invocations-level-'+level+' ~ ul:nth-of-type('+(index+1)+') li a.rating-' + colour)), function(el) {
    return el.parentElement.outerHTML;
}));
```

It looks like `ul:nth-of-type('+(index+1)` is needed, because it's never the nth-of-type that's a sibling of `#invocations-level-*` but in the selected parent's children. This makes sense when you remember [a CSS rule is read right-to-left](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5813672/1075247), so the `~` has to be evaluated after `nth-of-type`.

Comment: Right-to-left evaluation is an implementation detail meant to improve performance by starting from the subject itself - it's not the reason, nor does it affect, how a selector is *understood*. But it is a coincidence that we ignore the left hand side of the ~ and think of the ul:nth-of-type(index+1) on its own, which happens to be on the right hand side. As you've stated, :nth-of-type() isn't evaluated relative to the left hand side of the sibling selector - instead, it's relative to all the children of the element's parent (though, not relative to the whole document, but I get what you mean).

Comment: @BoltClock is it a coincidence though? It sounds logical to me, that the decision to make `nth-of-type` work the way it does, is because we have to initially select *all* ul elements, and can't narrow down by sibling until after doing that. I guess it's just semantics whether it's coincidental or not...

Answer (score 0):

you can do this purely with the use of CSS. However the class has to be applied directly to the `<li>` tag. Then use flexbox on the `<ul>` and apply the `order`-porperty to a class.

```css
ul { 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.rating-red {
  order: 1;
}

.rating-orange {
  order: 2;
}

.rating-blue {
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <!-- <li><a href="" class="rating-"></a><sup><a href="/dnd5/abbreviations/"></a></sup>: </li> -->
  <li class="rating-blue"><a href="https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/classes#AgonizingBlast">Agonizing Blast</a><sup><a href="/dnd5/abbreviations/">PHB</a></sup>: Nearly every Warlock takes this. The damage is simply too good to pass up. The damage grows
    multiplicatively as you get additional rays, so the total additional damage will range from +3 at low levels to a maximum +20 at 17th level.</li>
  <li class="rating-orange"><a href="https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/classes#ArmorofShadows">Armor of Shadows</a><sup><a href="/dnd5/abbreviations/">PHB</a></sup>: You already get light armor, and Mage Armor is only +1 AC over studded leather. You don't
    get enough invocations to justify wasting one on this. Hexblades might consider this to close the AC gap between light/medium and heavy armor, but I'm not convinced that this is better than multiclassing to get heavy armor proficiency.</li>
  <li class="rating-red"><a href="https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/classes#BeastSpeech">Beast Speech</a><sup><a href="/dnd5/abbreviations/">PHB</a></sup>: Very situational.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm not the owner of the site, so I can't change the html.

Comment: This is definitely useful for if/when I need it next though

Comment: you can use JS to add a class to the list item with `classList.add('class-name')` so you only have to check aprt of the inner HTML of a list for the class keyword and then apply the class to the `<li>` accourding to that. I can check again later if someone solves that issue. Otherwise I will write the script for that wehn I got more time.

Comment: I figured it out, see my answer